# Template Constraints C++

Tags: c++, templates, constraints

In C# we can define a generic type that imposes constraints on the types that can be used as the generic parameter. The following example illustrates the usage of generic constraints:

```
interface IFoo
{
}


class Foo<T> where T : IFoo
{
}

class Bar : IFoo
{
}

class Simpson
{
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Foo<Bar> a = new Foo<Bar>();
        Foo<Simpson> b = new Foo<Simpson>(); // error CS0309
    }
}
```

Is there a way we can impose constraints for template parameters in C++.

---

C++0x has native support for this but I am talking about current standard C++.

Comment: As Nemanja said, Boost has a library that implements something similar. It's a bit more verbose than if it had been a proper language feature, but it works, and it allows you to express most constraints.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

As someone else has mentioned, C++0x is getting this built into the language.  Until then, I'd recommend [Bjarne Stroustrup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bjarne_Stroustrup)'s [suggestions for template constraints](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#constraints).

Edit: [Boost](http://boost.org) also has an [alternative of its own](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/concept_check/concept_check.htm).

Edit2: Looks like [concepts have been removed from C++0x](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=441).

Comment: ... and possibly added back in [C++1y](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15669592/what-are-the-differences-between-concepts-and-template-constraints)

Comment: [Constraints and concepts](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints) will be added in c++20

Answer (score 87):

If you use C++11, you can use `static_assert` with `std::is_base_of` for this purpose.

For example,

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
class YourClass {

    YourClass() {
        // Compile-time check
        static_assert(std::is_base_of<BaseClass, T>::value, "type parameter of this class must derive from BaseClass");

        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect! *and I need more characters...*

Comment: This is helpful for compile time errors, but it isn't really a constraint. A constraint would be something that let you overload a template for `all arithmetic types` for example, so that the compiler can choose between the two templates based on the constraints.

Comment: @Troyseph Please mind when was this answered. I think it was not possible then, right ?

Answer (score 46):

"Implicitly" is the correct answer.  Templates effectively create a "duck typing" scenario, due to the way in which they are compiled.  You can call any functions you want upon a template-typed value, and the only instantiations that will be accepted are those for which that method is defined.  For example:

```
template <class T>
int compute_length(T *value)
{
    return value->length();
}
```

We can call this method on a pointer to any type which declares the `length()` method to return an `int`.  Thusly:

```
string s = "test";
vector<int> vec;
int i = 0;

compute_length(&s);
compute_length(&vec);
```

...but not on a pointer to a type which does *not* declare `length()`:

```
compute_length(&i);
```

This third example will not compile.

This works because C++ compiles a new version of the templatized function (or class) for each instantiation.  As it performs that compilation, it makes a direct, almost macro-like substitution of the template instantiation into the code prior to type-checking.  If everything still works with that template, then compilation proceeds and we eventually arrive at a result.  If anything fails (like `int*` not declaring `length()`), then we get the dreaded six page template compile-time error.

Comment: I guess you're saying it's sufficient to write it in a comment?  `//T must inherit from BaseA, otherwise compilation will fail`

Comment: `then we get the dreaded six page template compile-time error` (lol) because of this we all are waiting for the holy "concept" concept.

Answer (score 18):

You can put a guard type on IFoo that does nothing, make sure it's there on T in Foo:

```
class IFoo
{
public:
    typedef int IsDerivedFromIFoo;
};

template <typename T>
class Foo<T>
{
    typedef typename T::IsDerivedFromIFoo IFooGuard;
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Using C++20, yes there is: [Constraints and concepts](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints)

Perhaps you want to guarantee a template is derived from a specific class:

```
#include <concepts>

template<class T, class U>
concept Derived = std::is_base_of<U, T>::value;

class ABase { };
class ADerived : ABase { };

template<Derived<ABase> T>
class AClass {
    T aMemberDerivedFromABase;
};
```

The following then compiles like normal:

```
int main () {
    AClass<ADerived> aClass;
    return 0;
}
```

But now when you do something against the contraint:

```
class AnotherClass {

};
int main () {
    AClass<AnotherClass> aClass;
    return 0;
}
```

AnotherClass is not derived from ABase, therefore my compiler (GCC) gives roughly the following error:

> In function 'int main()': note: constraints not satisfied
> note: the expression 'std::is_base_of<U, T>::value
> [with U = ABase; T = AnotherClass]' evaluated to 'false'
> 9 | concept Derived = std::is_base_of<U, T>::value;

As you can imagine this feature is very useful and can do much more than constraining a class to have a specific base.

Comment: Good answer, +1. Only recently started getting into C++20, and there's a lot to wrap my head around! C++ really must be one of the biggest languages out there... the sheer amount of what you can do with the syntax (not even mentioning the standard library) is bewildering.

Answer (score 9):

Check out [Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/concept_check/concept_check.htm)

> The Boost Concept Check Library (BCCL)
>
> The Concept Check library allows one to add explicit statement and checking of [concepts](http://www.boost.org/more/generic_programming.html#concept) in the style of the [proposed C++ language extension](http://www.generic-programming.org/languages/conceptcpp/specification/).

Answer (score 2):

Sort of.  If you static_cast to an IFoo*, then it will be impossible to instantiate the template unless the caller passes a class that can be assigned to an IFoo *.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it. Create the base template. Make it have only Private constructors. Then create specializations for each case you want to allow (or make the opposite if the disallowed list is much smaller than the allowed list).

The compiler will not allow you to instantiate the templates that use the version with private constructors.

This example only allow instantiation with int and float.

```
template<class t> class FOO { private: FOO(){}};

template<> class FOO<int>{public: FOO(){}};

template<> class FOO<float>{public: FOO(){}};
```

Its not a short and elegant way of doing it,  but its possible.

Answer (score 1):

Only implicitly.
Any method you use in a method that is actually called is imposed on the template parameter.

Answer (score -1):

Look at the CRTP pattern (Curiously Recursive Template Pattern).  It is designed to help support static inheritence.

Comment: The CRTP isn't actually designed for anything particular... I think it was _discovered_ rather than designed (["The name of this idiom was coined by Jim Coplien, who had observed it in some of the earliest C++ template code."](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern)), though putting constraints on template parameters is certainly a use it happens to be very good at.