# Specialized template method with derived classes as argument

Tags: c++, templates, polymorphism

With a template method, that is specialized for a specific class A, is there a way to call the specialized code for the classes deriving from A ?

#### The minimal example

```
#include <iostream<  

class A
{};

class B : public A
{};

class Templator
{
public :
    template <class T>
    void dance(T *argument);
};

template <class T>
void Templator::dance(T *argument)
{
    std::cout << "General implementation" << std::endl;
}

template<>
void Templator::dance<A> (A* )
{
    std::cout << "Specialized implementation" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    A a;
    B b;

    Templator tt;
    tt.dance(&a);
    tt.dance(&b);

    return 0;
}
```

#### Corresponding output

> *Specialized implementation* 
>   *General implementation*

In other words, I would like the two outputs to be :

> *Specialized implementation* 
>   *Specialized implementation*

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4984502/force-template-class-to-be-derived-from-baseclassa

Comment: Thank you for the very instructing pointer !

Comment: You can have a look at this question I asked a while ago about this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7928871/20984

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++11 you can use `std::enable_if` and `std::is_base_and_derived`:

```
class Templator{
public :
    template <class T>
    typename std::enable_if<!std::is_base_and_derived<A, T>::value, void>::type 
    dance(T *argument) { 
       std::cout << "General implementation" << std::endl;
    }
    template <class T>
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_and_derived<A, T>::value, void>::type 
    dance(T *argument) { 
       std::cout << "Specialized implementation" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

You can do the same thing in C++03 using either `boost::enable_if_c` and `boost::is_base_of` or `std::tr1::is_base_of` and writing `enable_if` yourself (see [here](http://www.generic-programming.org/languages/cpp/techniques.php#overloading))

Comment: Thank you, I accepted your answer because it was illustrating the use of enable_if and is_base_of (that I obviously was not aware of the existence). And it is solving my specific problem, that's definitely a plus  ; )

Comment: I was about to advise you to use `disable_if<P>` instead of `enable_if<!P>`, before realizing it was not included in C++11 (like the original `boost::enable_if` taking a metafunction instead of a boolean)... However, they included the default parameter for the second parameter, so you can omit `void` if you want to avoid some clutter.

Comment: @LucTouraille: Personally I'd prefer explicitely stating the `void`, since even if it is a default parameter, I think explicitely mentioning the return type is a good idea to make the code clearer.

Comment: Sure, that's a tenable point of view :). I just made this remark for the OP's information.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to cast `&b` to a `A*`.

If you change this code

```
tt.dance(&a);
tt.dance(&b);
```

To this code

```
tt.dance(&a);
tt.dance((A*)&b);
```

The output becomes

```
Specialized implementation
Specialized implementation
```

Comment: Yes, it works (like calling `tt.dance<A>(&b)`), but I am sorry I oversimplified my problem. I would still need T to be resolved to B, because my real method implementation call different code in case T is an A or a B... and now that I phrases it, I understand that what I am asking is not possible because I want T to be a B and a A. Those Q&A websites are also good for self teaching ^^

Answer (score 1):

This should be possible using a [`boost::enable_if`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/utility/enable_if.html) in conjunction with [`boost::is_base_of`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/is_base_of.html).

Comment: Yes, it diverges from pure "specialization" to use SFINAE instead... but this is a way to make it work (cf. Lol4t0 pointer under the question)