# Detecting siblings of a CRTP base class

Tags: c++, inheritance, stl, sfinae, crtp

I am trying to use `boost::is_base_of` in order to detect if a CRTP base class `Generic` can identify its peers i.e. classes that `T` is also derived from.

As shown in `Generic<T>::init()`, I would like to use these mechanisms in order to allow the class `Generic<T>` add pointers to functions one of its peers `Bar1` or `Bar2` (from which `T` also derives) to a map. Unfortunately `boost::is_base_of` is unable to detect classes, such as `Bar3`, that `T` does not derive from.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <map>
#include <boost/type_traits.hpp>

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

template<typename T>
class Bar
{
public:
    void setValue()
    {
        std::cout << typeid(this).name() << std::endl;
    }
};

class Bar1 : public Bar<char>{};
class Bar2 : public Bar<bool>{};
class Bar3 : public Bar<long>{};

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

template<typename T>
class Generic
{
public:
    typedef void (T::*setter)();
    void init();
};

template<typename T>
void Generic<T>::init()
{
    std::map<std::string , Generic<T>::setter> setterMap;
    if( boost::is_base_of<Bar1, T >::value ) setterMap["bar1"] = &Bar1::setValue;
    if( boost::is_base_of<Bar2, T >::value ) setterMap["bar2"] = &Bar2::setValue;
    if( boost::is_base_of<Bar3, T >::value ) setterMap["bar3"] = &Bar3::setValue;
    std::cout << setterMap.size() << std::endl;
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

template<typename T>
class Foo : public Bar1 , public Bar2 , public Generic<Foo<T> >
{
public:

};

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

int main()
{
    Foo<int> f;
    f.init();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

gcc error message:

```
In static member function ‘static void Generic<T>::init() [with T = Foo<int>]’:
error: cannot convert ‘void (Bar<long int>::*)()’ to ‘void (Foo<int>::*)()’ in assignment
```

**Edit**

To provide some context for this question. I'm trying to store pointers to the `setValue` methods of the base classes of each `Foo<T>` in a map for quick access. The choice of `setValue` to call depends on a string, thus the map. Another class `X` may inherit `Bar1` and `Bar3` but not `Bar2`, and as before I would have to store pointers to the appropriate `setValue`'s for quick access. `Generic<T>` aims to fulfil this role for `Foo`, `X` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jay is correct.  I made the following changes and this appears to work.

```
template <bool, typename T> struct AddSetter;

template <typename T> struct AddSetter <true, T>
{
    template<typename F>
    void Set (std::map<std::string , typename Generic<T>::setter>& setterMap, const std::string& key, F fn)
    {
        setterMap[key] = fn;
    }
};

template <typename T> struct AddSetter <false, T>
{
    template<typename F>
    void Set (std::map<std::string , typename Generic<T>::setter>& setterMap, const std::string& key, F fn)
    {
    }
};

template<typename T>
void Generic<T>::init()
{
    std::map<std::string , Generic<T>::setter> setterMap;
    AddSetter<boost::is_base_of<Bar1, T >::value, T>().Set (setterMap, "bar1", &Bar1::setValue);
    AddSetter<boost::is_base_of<Bar2, T >::value, T>().Set (setterMap, "bar2", &Bar2::setValue);
    AddSetter<boost::is_base_of<Bar3, T >::value, T>().Set (setterMap, "bar3", &Bar3::setValue);
    std::cout << setterMap.size() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Finally! Can I get a up vote? BTW who is your daddy? C'mon now... tell me :P

Comment: Btw, Nice example... I didn't have time since I was in a rush to smoke weed

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head I just can't envision this working without a middle man...

Is it possible to create a struct which encapsulates the desired logic with operator overloading? The struct would have a raw pointer and then you could deference it with an overload to ensure it was used correctly.

Another seemingly readable way is to create another forward facing class which acts as a Facade and then utilize that.

This is similar to [Override contra-variance workaround needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7144893/override-contra-variance-workaround-needed)