# How can I create a compile time assertion that a template is of specific types?

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors

I have a template function and wish to ensure at compile time that it is not instantiated on a subtype or supertype of a particular class.

How can I cause a C++ compiler error if this is violated?

```
class base {
};
class derived : public base {
};
class lowest : public derived {
};

template <typename T>
bool isCorrect(const T& obj) {
  typedef foo<T> D;
  foo<T> *def = foo<T>::find();
  return (def && def->getAnswer(object));
}
```

I want `isCorrect` to only be available for class `derived`, but not `base` or `lowest`.  Note there could be many other lowest classes and a string of base classes to be excluded as well as alternative derived classes that are acceptable.

Is there a way in C++ to limit the template to only apply to the derived classes I explicitly specify?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Template Constraints C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122316/template-constraints-c)

Comment: Specifically, this might be useful: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/concept_check/concept_check.htm

Comment: Why don't you just write overloads?

Comment: @GMan There are a lot of sub types, so the list would be pretty long, so I'm looking for way to instead positively declare the acceptable ones.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one technique that I know of.

First, make another template class `policy_enforcer`. Declare this class *without defining it*, and also provide a specialization of it for `derived` *that is also defined*:

```
template<typename T> struct policy_enforcer;
template<> struct policy_enforcer<derived> { };
```

Then, within the function you wish to lock down, include the expression `sizeof(policy_enforcer<T>)`. Since `sizeof` on incomplete types is a compilation error, this will prevent the code from compiling.

**Updated with live code:** [using `base`](http://www.ideone.com/puXqG), [using `derived`](http://www.ideone.com/uOdLk), [using `lowest`](http://www.ideone.com/VAAzZ).

Comment: A bit obtuse, but it would work.  Hopefully someone will post a way that is not so obscure.

Answer (score 10):

Type traits, specifically `is_base_of`.

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
bool isCorrect(const T& obj) {
  static bool const is_base = std::is_base_of<base, T>::value;
  static bool const derives = std::is_base_of<derived, T>::value;
  // specify allowed types here
  static bool const is_derived = std::is_same<T, derived>::value;
  // ---
  static_assert((!is_base && !derives) || is_derived, "wrong argument type");

  typedef foo<T> D;
  foo<T> *def = foo<T>::find();
  return (def && def->getAnswer(object));
}
```

Note that this is C++11 specific, but you can get the same behaviour with Boost.TypeTraits.

Answer (score 1):

**You can use template specialization.**

You can implement only the `isCorrect` only for types that you want to be able to work with.

For the other types you can implement dummy method, returning `false` for example, or not implement `isCorrect` at all, in which case it will not compile for other types.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class base {
};
class derived : public base {
};
class lowest : public derived {
};

// using this it will fail if you try to pass anything
// else than `derived`
//  template <typename T>
//     bool isCorrect(const T& obj);

template <typename T>
bool isCorrect(const T& obj) {
    cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << endl;
    return false;
}

template <>
bool isCorrect<derived>(const derived& obj) {
    cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << endl;
    return true;
//  typedef foo<derived> D;
//  foo<derived> *def = foo<derived>::find();
//  return (def && def->getAnswer(object));
}
```

Test:

```
int main()
{
    base b;
    derived d;
    lowest l;

    cout << isCorrect(b) << endl;
    cout << isCorrect(d) << endl;
    cout << isCorrect(l) << endl;
}
```

Output:

```
bool isCorrect(const T&) [with T = base]
0
bool isCorrect(const T&) [with T = derived]
1
bool isCorrect(const T&) [with T = lowest]
0
```

Comment: `__func__` is the C++11 equivalent of `__FUNCTION__`, `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` etc.

Comment: It is not equivalent .... Firstly, I don't see any requirement for C++11, anything wrong with `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` , it wasn't part of the question, btw thanks for the info :) ? With `__func__` or `__FUNCTION__` you only get `isCorrect` or `isCorrect<derived>` so you don't see the other types that called the non-specialized version ....

Comment: Nothing wrong, I just wanted to mention that, since C++11 is the current standard. Everything else (`__FUNCTION__`, `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`, etc) is non-standard and non-portable most of the time. :)