# C++ - generic type where type variable must have specific type

Tags: c++, templates

Let's say I have a `Server` class, with a template argument. I need to ensure that the argument is a subclass of another `Client` class. Is it possible in C++?

For example, given something like this:

```
template <typename CLIENT>
class Server {
  void addClient(CLIENT client);
};
```

I'm expecting something like this:

```
template <typename CLIENT : Client>
class Server {
  void addClient(CLIENT client);
}
```

I want to have `LoginServer` and `GameServer`, both based on `Server` class, but each will work with different `Client` subclass.

```
class LoginServer : public Server<LoginClient>
class GameServer : public Server<GameClient>
```

I don't want to retype all `Client` types to `LoginClient` inside the LoginServer, otherwise compiler will throws error because of undefined methods etc. (`LoginClient` can have methods that `Client` hasn't, it's subclass).

Comment: This seems like a case where you shouldn't be using templates at all, and just accepting a `const Client&` (so any object of a class derived from `Client` can be passed in by reference)

Comment: To answer the general question, no. Unlike in Java, in C++ you cannot constrain the type of the class in a template. The logic being that if you are doing so, you're not actually making a truly templated class and can generally just use polymorphism.

Comment: Lots of ways to do it, e.g. just put a `static_cast<Client*>(CLIENT*(0))` in the constructor.  You'd probably have liked the Concepts proposed C++ which sadly didn't make it in to the C++11 Standard - they offered a dedicated mechanism for this, but at the cost of less readable compiler error messages and a few edge cases, this suffices.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Template Constraints C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122316/template-constraints-c)

Comment: @Brian: lots of differences/benefits specific to templates - inlining, dead code elimination, static array sizing, loop unrolling etc., sometimes it's desirable to have distinct types instead of just Server.  Of course some potential disadvantages too.

Comment: `static_assert(std::is_base_of<Client, CLIENT>::value, "...")` in the constructor maybe

Comment: @krab: You say: 'I need to ensure that the client is subclass of Client class'. Why? Templates in C++ are resolved at compile time. If you do anything unsupported by the type you get a compile time error. Just assume CLIENT is a Client and treat it like a Client. If something goes wrong youll get a compile time error.

Comment: @Muepe: hm yes, you are right. But it can be class with same interface or something like that. You know, i am confused why in Java this behavior is, if it looks like it is not necessary.

Comment: @Krab Java and C++ are different languages. And C++ templates are different from Java generics. It sounds like you don't actually need to enforce the requirement that the `CLIENT` template parameter type inherits from `Client`. So don't. :) In Java you might have needed to enforce that, but in C++ you most likely don't.

Comment: @Krab: Java is a bit a dull example as its a big mess when it comes to generics/templates. It tries some sort of C++s 'Do whatever you want' attitude with C#s (yea, I know it was after Java) 'You can only do what your constraints say' approach. Compare it to C#. In C# generic classes/methods are actually compiled to code. The constraints are therefore neccessary to make sure the end user (who faces compiled code) knows if he can feed a type to the class/method. In C++ no template code gets compiled unless it gets used. Every bit of code using a template has to be fully aware for the user

Comment: of the template. Therefore the user can exactly say "Uhm, sorry, that wont work" as he has the full code and then compiles it with the type replaced by what he enters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Let's say I have a Server class, with a template argument. I need to ensure that the argument is a subclass of another Client class. Is it possible in C++?

You can use *type traits*, specifically you can enable the class template via [`std::enable_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) in conjunction with [`std::is_base_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of):

```
template<class T, class Enable = void>
class Server;

template <typename CLIENT>
class Server<CLIENT, typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<Client, CLIENT>::value>::type> {};
```

So that give this hierarchy:

```
class Client {};
class Derived : public Client {};
class NonDerived {};
```

The following [would compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e1ffef3784ab6145):

```
Server<Derived> x;
```

but the following [wouldn't](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/de3167cbbbf310f3):

```
Server<NonDerived> x;
```

---

Alternatively, as suggested in the comments, you could you [`static_assert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert) within the class:

```
template <typename CLIENT>
class Server {
    static_assert(std::is_base_of<Client, CLIENT>::value, "CLIENT must be derived from Client");
    // ...
};
```

Comment: I'd probably use a `static_assert` in the class instead, for saner compiler messages.

Comment: @MooingDuck, In every constructor?

Comment: Even if you don't have c++11, you can use BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT or BOOST_MPL_ASSERT_MSG or something.

Comment: @Jefffrey you can place `static_assert` in the class itself http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/44a36b737193fcf8