# Defining template inheritance by the arguments in c++

Tags: c++

I have a polymorphic template MyClass that takes argument T.

```
template<class T>
class MyClass {...};
```

I would like to force an inheritance without specifing it in every derieved class, something like:

```
template<class T, class U : public T>
class MyClass<U> : public MyClass<T>;
```

Is there a way to do it?

EDIT:
For Example If I have

```
class Base {...};
class Derieved : public Base {...};
```

Then if the compiler creates `MyClass<Derieved>` then it would add

```
class MyClass<Derieved> : public MyClass<Base>
```

without specifing it every time I use MyClass with inheritance.

I want to be able to create MyClass with any parameter, but when the
parameter inherits from some other class, so will the template.

Comment: Huh? What do you want to inherit from what? Can you provide an example?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122316/template-constraints-c not tried it, but `static_assert` mixed with `std::is_base_of seems` like the best option.

Comment: The problem isn't only to make the compiler check if there is an inheritance, but to create an inheritance based on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to automatically retrieve the base classes of an object. Sadly, it won't be possible before at least C++17, when compile-time reflection is integrated.