# How to enforce derived class members on derived classes

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, design-patterns

How does one enforce a derived class to have member data of a specific derived type.

i.e.,

```
class Project {
  public:
    int projdata;
};

class Article: public Project {
};

class Building: public Project {
};

class Emplooyee {
  public:
    std::vector<Project> projs;
}

class Architect: public Employee {
};

class Writer: public Employee {
};
```

How do I now enforce that Architect objects only have projects of type Building, while Novelist only have projects of type Article? i.e., I want to have something like

```
class Architect: public Employee {
  public:
    std::vector<Building> projs;
};
```

and

```
class Novelist: public Employee {
  public:
    std::vector<Article> projs;
};
```

I could also store pointers to projects and then store cast them into the correct type. Is there a technique or design pattern to enforce such corresponding inheritance rules on members of derived classes?

Comment: You can just make Employee a template with the project subtype as a type parameter. Or keep Employee and have an intermediate EmployeeImpl template to automate the casting.

Comment: This is a massive anti-pattern in OOP. Why do you care what _data_ the class stores? What, specifically, do you want to do, and why can't it be a member function instead of a member variable?

Answer (score 3):

A compile time solution is to make the base a template:

```
template<class Proj>
class Emplooyee {
  public:
    std::vector<Proj> projs;
}

class Architect: public Employee<Building> {};

class Writer: public Employee<Article> {};
```

Additionally, you can add a one additional non-template base so that `Architect` and `Writer` are part of same hierarchy, but that non-template base cannot deal with the `projs` member.

If a template not an option, then you must rely on runtime checks. For that, `Project` must be a polymorphic type, and you must use `typeid` or `dynamic_cast`, to enforce the invariant. And you must use indirection to store the `Project`'s in the first place. `std::vector<Project>` cannot store any `Building` nor `Article` objects because it only stores `Project` objects only

Comment: Also template argument could be constrained at compile time, e.g. required to be derived from `Project` (ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22934960/1075282)

Answer (score 0):

Like you mentioned, you could store polymorphic pointers in the base class:

```
class Employee {
  public:
    std::vector<Project*> projs;
}
```

And use `dynamic_cast` to downcast them:

```
dynamic_cast<Building*>(projs[i])->doSomething();
```

But I wouldn't recommend this approach(unless necessary) since this will require you to manage the memory behind those pointers. (Which of course can be off-loaded to `std::unique_ptr` for example.)

Unless you require the Employee to be a polymorphic class, far simpler approach would be to use a class template

```
template <typename T>
class Employee {
public:
    std::vector<T> projs;
}
```

which can be used like so:

```
class Architect : public Employee<Building> {
};

Architect architect;
architect.projs.push_back(Building());
```

Comment: `Project` must have at least one virtual method to enable `dynamic_cast`