# In C++, is it safe to extend scope via a reference?

Tags: c++, reference, scope

In C++, is it safe to extend scope via a reference?

In code, what I mean is:

```
MyCLass& function badIdea()
{
    MyClass obj1;
    ...
    return obj1;
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It is NOT safe to extend the scope via reference. Objects in C++ are not reference counted when obj1 goes out of scope it will be deleted, refering to the result of badIdea() will only get you into trouble

Comment: The question was about C++ and reference binding. Reference counting does not enter into it. I've added an answer of my own, but briefly, you *can* extend the scope of an object by reference binding but should be careful in your design. Don't do it if you don't understand it.

Comment: I think he referred to reference counting since that is how you *could* return a reference without the local object going out of scope in languages that support reference counting (C++ not being one of them, of course).

Comment: I can see how the term "reference counting" muddies the issues, i was trying to hint to mechanisms that other languages have that might keep allocated objects alive, maybe not a good idea

Answer (score 16):

The only place it's OK to extend a scope with a reference is with a `const` reference in `namespace` or function scope (not with class members).

```
const int & cir = 1+1; // OK to use cir = 2 after this line
```

This trick is used in [Andrei Alexandrescu's](http://erdani.org/) very cool [scope guard](http://www.ddj.com/cpp/184403758) in order to capture a `const` reference to a base class of the concrete scope guard.

Comment: Note this is only "extending the scope" in the sense the the usually very narrow "scope" of a temporary is extended to the parent scope, which is quite different to what the OP was asking. Kudos for mentioning a little known aspect of C++ that a lot of people are confused by at first.

Answer (score 1):

Please clarify what you do mean.

Assuming you intend to do this:

```
int * p = NULL;
{
  int y = 22;
  p = &y;
}
*p = 77; // BOOM!
```

Then no, absolutely not, scope does not get extended by having a reference.

You may want to look at smart pointers, e.g. from boost libraries: [clickety](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/smart_ptr/smart_ptr.htm)

Comment: references act the same as pointers, only they can't be re-bound