# In C++, if throw is an expression, what is its type?

Tags: c++, throw

I picked this up in one of my brief forays to reddit:

http://www.smallshire.org.uk/sufficientlysmall/2009/07/31/in-c-throw-is-an-expression/

Basically, the author points out that in C++:

```
throw "error"
```

is an expression. This is actually fairly clearly spelt out in the C++ Standard, both in the main text and the grammar. However, what is not clear (to me at least) is what is the type of the expression? I guessed "`void`", but a bit of experimenting with g++ 4.4.0 and Comeau yielded this code:

```
    void f() {
    }

    struct S {};

    int main() {
        int x = 1;
        const char * p1 = x == 1 ? "foo" : throw S();  // 1
        const char * p2 = x == 1 ? "foo" : f();        // 2
    }
```

The compilers had no problem with //1 but barfed on //2 because the the types in the conditional operator are different. So the type of a `throw` expression does not seem to be void.

So what is it?

If you answer, please back up your statements with quotes from the Standard.

---

**This turned out not to be so much about the type of a throw expression as how the conditional operator deals with throw expressions - something I certainly didn't 
know about before today. Thanks to all who replied, but particularly to David Thornley.**

Comment: That link seems to make it fairly clear that the type is determined by the compiler to be whatever it needs to be.

Comment: The linked article has I think been updated since I looked at it, and I'm sure that is in fact the case. However, I can't find it in the standard.

Comment: Aand maybe not - double d = throw "foo"; is an error with g+= (haven't tested it with comeau)

Answer (score 97, accepted):

According to the standard, 5.16 paragraph 2 first point, "The second or the third operand (but not both) is a throw-expression (15.1); the result is of the type of the other and is an rvalue."  Therefore, the conditional operator doesn't care what type a throw-expression is, but will just use the other type.

In fact, 15.1, paragraph 1 says explicitly "A throw-expression is of type void."

Comment: OK - I think we have a winner.

Comment: Note that throw-expression are assignment-expression.  So they are a syntax error as an argument to most operators.  Obviously, you can hide them in parenthesis, but if they aren't ignored (first argument of builtin operator , for instance), it is a type error.

Comment: What really surprises me is that they thought of this case and made something reasonable happen.

Answer (score 33):

> "A throw-expression is of type void"

ISO14882 Section 15

Comment: Then both g++ and Comeau are remiss in not giving an error for my //1 case?

Comment: @Neil, not really because according to C++/5.16/2, second and third operands of the conditional operator can be of type of `void`

Answer (score 13):

From [expr.cond.2] (conditional operator `?:`):

> If either the second or the third operand has type (possibly cv-qualiﬁed) void, then the lvalue-to-rvalue,
>   array-to-pointer, and function-to-pointer standard conversions are performed on the second and
>   third operands, and one of the following shall hold:
>
> — The second or the third operand (but not both) is a throw-expression;
>     the result is of the type of the other and is an rvalue.
>
> — Both the second and the third operands have type void;
>     the result is of type void and is an rvalue.
>     [ Note: this includes the case where both operands are throw-expressions. — end note ]

So, with `//1` you were in the first case, with `//2`, you were violating "one of the following shall hold", since none of them do, in that case.

Answer (score 4):

You can have a type printer [spit it out for you](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1332e4c9e6348b54) :

```
template<typename T>
struct PrintType;

int main()
{
    PrintType<decltype(throw "error")> a; 
}
```

Basically the lack of implementation for `PrintType` will cause the compilation error report to say :

> implicit instantiation of undefined template `PrintType<void>`

so we can actually verify that `throw` expressions are of type `void` (and yes, the Standard quotes mentioned in other answers verify that this isn't an implementation specific outcome - though gcc has a hard time printing valuable info)