# Throw exception from constructor initializer

Tags: c++, exception, ctor-initializer

What is the best way to throw exception from the constructor initializer?

For example:

```
class C {
  T0 t0; // can be either valid or invalid, but does not throw directly
  T1 t1; // heavy object, do not construct if t0 is invalid,  by throwing before
  C(int n)
    : t0(n), // throw exception if t0(n) is not valid
      t1() {}
};
```

I thought maybe making wrapper, e.g. `t0(throw_if_invalid(n))`.

What is the practice to handle such cases?

Comment: How does `T0` notify of failure? Is there some function such as `bool bad()`, for example?

Comment: @GMan T0 does not notify of failure.  it is basically int struct, values of which can be too much for hardware to handle (block dimensions in CUDA multiplied by register usage).

Comment: Hm, so is the valid range of the type dynamic?

Comment: @GMan yes, but I can work with your or Billy solution

Comment: Unrelated, but you probably want to make C's constructor `explicit`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways of going about this, I think. From what I understand, `n` can only take on a specific range of numbers. For that, you might prevent the constructor from even being run:

```
template <typename T, T Min, T Max>
class ranged_type_c
{
public:
    typedef T value_type;

    ranged_type_c(const value_type& pX) :
    mX(pX)
    {
        check_value();
    }

    const value_type& get(void) const
    {
        return mX;
    }

    operator const value_type&(void) const
    {
        return get();
    }

    // non-const overloads would probably require a proxy
    // of some sort, to ensure values remain valid

private:
    void check_value(void)
    {
        if (mX < Min || mX > Max)
            throw std::range_error("ranged value out of range");
    }

    value_type mX;
};
```

Could be more fleshed out, but that's the idea. Now you can clamp the range:

```
struct foo_c
{
    foo_c(ranged_value_c<int, 0, 100> i) :
    x(i)
    {}

    int x;
};
```

If you pass a value that does not lie from 0-100, the above would throw.

---

At runtime, I think your original idea was best:

```
template <typename T>
const T& check_range(const T& pX, const T& pMin, const T& pMax)
{
    if (pX < pMin || pX > pMax)
        throw std::range_error("ranged value out of range");

    return pValue;
}

struct foo
{
    foo(int i) :
    x(check_range(i, 0, 100))
    {}

    int x;
}
```

And that's it. Same as above, but 0 and 100 can be replaced with a call to some function that returns the valid minimum and maximum.

If you do end up using a function call to get valid ranges (recommended, to keep clutter to a minimum and organization higher), I'd add an overload:

```
template <typename T>
const T& check_range(const T& pX, const std::pair<T, T>& pRange)
{
    return check_range(pX, pRange.first, pRange.second); // unpack
}
```

To allow stuff like this:

```
std::pair<int, int> get_range(void)
{
    // replace with some calculation
    return std::make_pair(0, 100);
}

struct foo
{
    foo(int i) :
    x(check_range(i, get_range()))
    {}

    int x;
}
```

If I were to choose, I'd pick the runtime methods even if the range was compile-time. Even with low optimization the compiler will generate the same code, and it's much less clumsy and arguably cleaner to read than the class version.

Comment: okay, this is cleaner than function wrapper.  quick think about my problem tells me it is a good solution

Comment: clever thing by the way. definitely goes into my solutions Kit

Comment: your solution gave me some unrelated idea of how to optimize certain thinks. Thanks

Comment: GManNickG, I'm unfamiliar with the syntax you've used for the ?functor? in this template class.  Please explain the syntax.  I know what it's doing, I'm just not sure how the mechanics work.  What's tripping me up is: operator const value_type&(void) const.  Are you overloading "const"?  Why aren't there two sets of parentheses for this functor?

Comment: @AndrewFalanga: That's a conversion operator, like in this: `struct foo { operator float() { return 5; } }; foo x; float y = x;`.

Answer (score 8):

You can `throw` from the expression(s) that initialize `t0` or `t1`, or any constructor that takes at least one argument.

```
class C {
  T0 t0; // can be either valid or invalid, but does not throw directly
  T1 t1; // heavy object, do not construct if t0 is invalid, by throwing before
  C(int n) // try one of these alternatives:
    : t0( n_valid( n )? n : throw my_exc() ), // sanity pre-check
OR    t1( t0.check()? throw my_exc() : 0 ), // add dummy argument to t1::t1()
OR    t1( t0.check()? throw my_exc() : t1() ) // throw or invoke copy/move ctor
      {}
};
```

Note that a `throw` expression has `void` type, making `throw` more like an operator than a statement. The `?:` operator has a special case to prevent that `void` from interfering with its type deduction.

Comment: +1. Just an FYI though, `class empty` incurs overhead the size of a pointer despite the fact that it has no data members.

Comment: nice one ... I would have given 2 points for this if I could!

Answer (score 2):

This is a way to throw from the initializer list

```
C(int n)
    : t0(n > 0 ? n : throw std::runtime_error("barf")),
      t1() {}
```

You're saying "throw exception if t0(n) is not valid".
Why don't you throw from the constructor of T0?

An object is supposed to be valid after construction.

Comment: You need a comma after the `throw` to avoid passing `void`.

Comment: @Potato: I don't see what you mean.

Comment: throw doesn't have a return type and it doesn't matter because we are leaving the building. On the other hand, there are compilers.

Comment: @Eddy, @GMan: throw returns `void` and `?:` returns whichever of its alternative types converts to the other. `int` converts to `void` and `void` does not convert to `int` so the result of the whole expression is `void`.

Comment: @Potato: In a conditional operator, a throw-expression will take on the type of the other branch in the ternary. Neil asked this once: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212978/in-c-if-throw-is-an-expression-what-is-its-type :)

Comment: Oops, 5.16/3 is a specific special case for throw-expressions inside the conditional operator. Never mind. — lol, I'm on a roll correcting myself simultaneously with being corrected by others on this question.

Comment: @eddy the object is invalid in a sense that hardware may not like values in it.  it is a configuration parameter divorced from actual hardware

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap class T0 inside another class which *does* throw in cases like this:

```
class ThrowingT0
{
    T0 t0;
public:
    explicit ThrowingT0(int n) : t0(n) {
        if (t0.SomeFailureMode())
            throw std::runtime_error("WTF happened.");
    };
    const T0& GetReference() const {
        return t0;
    };
    T0& GetReference() {
        return t0;
    };
};

class C
{
    ThrowingT0 t0;
    T1 t1;
public:
    explicit C(int n) : t0(n), t1() {
    };
    void SomeMemberFunctionUsingT0() {
        t0.GetReference().SomeMemberFunction();
    };
};
```