# Why is throw an expression?

Tags: c++

The following post discusses the type of a `throw` expression: [In C++, if throw is an expression, what is its type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212978/in-c-if-throw-is-an-expression-what-is-its-type). I would like to clarify a more basic thing: why should `throw` be an expression and not a (non-expression) statement just like `return` in the first place? I mean, would anyone want to write something like `auto x = throw std::runtime_error("Error message")`?

Answer (score 12):

If `throw` were a statement you couldn't use it with the conditional operator.

```
return success()
    ? computation()
    : throw std::runtime_error("oops");
```

<sup><sub>Note : this may or may not have uses outside code obfuscation.</sub></sup>

Edit : one useful case is inside C++11's strict `constexpr` functions which can only contain one instruction. Thanks @dyp for the insight !

Comment: Another +1 for the note, which I would appreciate someone commenting on. It looks like I cannot vote twice :(

Comment: Plus one, although worth noting perhaps that `throw std::runtime_error("oops")` is an expression of type `void` and it only works in a conditional due to some technical trickery that prevents me from answering this myself.

Comment: @Bathsheba `return throw std::runtime_error("oops"), 0;` works too (thanks, comma operator from outer space !)

Comment: @Quentin Could you please explain what the line of code in your comment does?

Comment: @MeirGoldenberg the comma operator evaluates and discards its left operand, then evaluates and returns its right operand. Here, it will just throw the exception everytime, so this is not really useful *but* it's syntactically correct.

Comment: *"Note : this may or may not have uses outside code obfuscation."* It is an important technique in C++11 constexpr functions. Those may only contain a return statement (plus declarations), so an if-statement is usually replaced by a ternary operator. Note that throwing exceptions is allowed inside constexpr functions; if the throw is invoked at compile-time, the compiler will report an error (which is what you'd want).

Comment: @dyp I thought about constexpr functions, but for some reason I was certain that throwing from one would be *really* bad. Well I'll edit this in then, thanks :)

Comment: What is the type of this expression?

Comment: @sbabbi as stated in the linked question, the type of a throw-expression is `void`.

Comment: On the other hand, `throw` being an expression predates `constexpr`. Therefore, I'm not sure that being able to put a `throw` into a conditional statement was enough of a motivation.

Comment: @Morwenn it is the only useful context that I know of which accepts `void` expressions. The other two being the `return` statement of a `void` function, and the comma operator. So, it was probably more of a lack of motivation to prohibiting it by making `throw` a statement.