# Is there an C++ equivalent to Python's "import bigname as b"?

Tags: c++, python, namespaces, alias

I've always liked Python's

```
import big_honkin_name as bhn
```

so you can then just use `bhn.thing` rather than the considerably more verbose `big_honkin_name.thing` in your source.

I've seen two type of namespace use in C++ code, either:

```
using namespace big_honkin_name; // includes fn().
int a = fn (27);
```

(which I'm assured is a *bad* thing) or:

```
int a = big_honkin_name::fn (27);
```

Is there a way to get Python functionality in C++ code, something like:

```
alias namespace big_honkin_name as bhn;
int a = bhn::fn (27);
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
namespace bhn = big_honkin_name;
```

There's another way to use namespaces too:

```
using big_honkin_name::fn;
int a = fn(27);
```

Comment: Aah, the equivalent to the "from big_honkin_name import fn". Nice to know that one as well.

Answer (score 12):

[StackOverflow to the rescue!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75538/hidden-features-of-c/78484#78484) Yes you can. In short:

```
namespace bhn = big_honkin_name;
```

Answer (score 6):

It is easy..

```
namespace bhn = big_honkin_name;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
using big_honkin_name::fn;
```

to import all functions named `fn` from the namespace `big_honkin_name`, so that you can then write

```
int a = fn(27);
```

But that doesn't let you shrink down the name itself.  To do (something similar to but not exactly) that, you could do as follows:

```
int big_honkin_object_name;
```

You can later use:

```
int& x(big_honkin_object_name);
```

And thereafter treat `x` the same as you would `big_honkin_object_name`.  The compiler will in most cases eliminate the implied indirection.

Answer (score 2):

Nicely put, C++ equivalent for Python imports are:

### Python to C++

`import someLib as sl` ***=>*** `namespace sl = someLib;`

`from someLib import func` ***->*** `using someLib::func;`

`from someLib import *` ***->*** `using namespace someLib;`

note that you must do the `#include<someLib>` in C++ before these.

#### the last one is quite famous!

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
using namespace big_honkin_name;
```

Is not a bad thing.  Not at all.  Used judiciously, bringing namespaces into scope *improves* clarity of code by removing unnecessary clutter.

(Unless it's in a header file in which case it's *very* poor practice.)

But yes, as others have pointed out you can create a namespace alias:

```
namespace big = big_honkin_name;
```

Comment: In fact I recall an expert recommending that in some obscure circumstance (that I can't recall) you *should* create a new block scope and use "using namespace XYZ;" before calling the unqualified `some_func()` in preference to calling `XYZ::some_func()`, since the former will interfere with name lookup less. Wish I could recall the specifics -- anyone?