# Function template specialization importance and necessity

Tags: c++, template-specialization

I read C++ Primer, and it says function template specialization is an advanced topic, but I am totally lost.  Can anybody offer an example why function template specialization is important and necessary?

Why don't function templates support partial specialization while class templates do? What's the underlying logic?

Comment: Oh please, could we avoid the english vs american debate ? Who cares if some use an `s` and others a `z` ?

Comment: :) I see how it looks now... But previously the question said "template specification". I don't care about s vs. z.  Deleted the comment anyway as it's no longer necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically the idea is that you can write templates that behave in a generic way for the general case, but can still handle special cases.  One example of where specialization is used is in `std::vector`.  `std::vector<bool>` is a specialization that packs the `bool` elements such that they only use one bit per element, not one byte.  `std::vector<T>` works like a normal dynamic array for all other types.

The more advanced use for specialization is metaprogramming.  For example, here's an example (from Wikipedia) of how to use template specialization to compute factorials at compile time.

```
template <int N>
struct Factorial 
{
    enum { value = N * Factorial<N - 1>::value };
};

template <>
struct Factorial<0> 
{
    enum { value = 1 };
};
```

Comment: Yeh, vector<bool> is not the greatest example :)

Comment: Not *function* template specialization that was asked about.

Comment: Have to agree with Roger Pate sorry, -1.

Answer (score 9):

Your question of why functions do not support partial specialization can be answered [here](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm). The code below shows how to implement the different specializations.

```
template<typename T>
bool Less(T a, T b)
{
    cout << "version 1 ";
    return a < b;
}
// Function templates can't be partially specialized they can overload instead.
template<typename T>
bool Less(T* a, T* b)
{
    cout << "version 2 ";
    return *a < *b;
}

template<>
bool Less<>(const char* lhs, const char* rhs)
{
    cout << "version 3 ";
    return strcmp(lhs, rhs) < 0;
}

int a = 5, b = 6;

cout << Less<int>(a, b) << endl;
cout << Less<int>(&a, &b) << endl;
cout << Less("abc", "def") << endl;
```

Comment: You can drop the `<int>` on the first two Less calls in the output statements.

Comment: Could you make it clearer: often times specialization is not necessary for functions because there is already overloading that allows a single symbol to represent multiple functions and a decision mechanism to choose (resolve) which function to use based on a set of rules.

Comment: Great link. For me the most important point of that article was that function specialisations don't influence *which* function gets called -- they come into play only *after* the final template types have been decided. Overloading OTOH introduces a new "competitor" into the "which function should we call" competition.

Comment: This is a decent example of specialization and the link is great, but on second look I see nothing that says why function specialization is either important or necessary, and that, the way I read it, is what the OP is really asking.  (I'm sure their book provides example of how to specialize, for example.)

Answer (score 3):

I cannot think of an example, and I've been trying nearly since you asked.  As pointed out by [Jagannath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2197141/why-template-specialization-is-important-and-necessary-in-c/2197262#2197262), it's been [long-standing advice](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm) not to specialize functions, but instead overload them or use a traits class (which *can* be specialized, even partially specialized).

For example, if you need to swap two items, then relying on overloads is better (more predictable and more extensible):

```
template<class T>
void f() {
  T a, b;
  using std::swap; // brings std::swap into scope as "fallback"
  swap(a, b); // unqualified call (no "std::") so ADL kicks in
  // also look at boost::swap
}
```

And how you write a swap for your types:

```
// the cleanest way to do it for a class template:
template<class T>
struct Ex1 {
  friend void swap(Ex1& a, Ex1& b) { /* do stuff */ }
};

// you can certainly place it outside of the class instead---but in the
// same namespace as the class---if you have some coding convention
// against friends (which is common, but misguided, IMHO):
struct Ex2 {};
void swap(Ex2& a, Ex2& b) { /* do stuff */ }
```

Both of which allow [Argument Dependent Lookup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_dependent_name_lookup) (ADL).

Other functions, such as a stringify/str or a repr (representation) can similarly be non-members and take advantage of ADL through overloading:

```
struct Ex3 {
  friend std::string repr(Ex3 const&) { return "<Ex3 obj>"; }
};

std::string repr(bool b) { return b ? "true" : "false"; }

// possible fallback:
template<class T>
std::string repr(T const& v) {
  std::ostringstream out;
  out << v;
  return out.str();
}
// but in this particular case, I'd remove the fallback and document that
// repr() must be overloaded appropriately before it can be used with a
// particular type; for other operations a default fallback makes sense
```

To look at it another way, it would be nice if function templates could serve as a *registry* for specific implementations, but due to limits (in current C++, not sure exactly what C++0x brings here) they don't work as well as either overloading or class templates for that registry purpose.

There is one use that is convenient but *not important*: easily defining certain specializations to be in a separate library, possibly a shared library (.so or .dll).  This is convenient because it requires minimal changes to the generic template, but not important because it seems rare to me (in the wild, and certainly is rare in my experience) and implementors can still use either overloading or forwarding to a fully-specialized class template's unspecialized method.

Comment: Great answer. One thing though: I think your friend declaration in the 3rd code snippet needs the full template-ID syntax (`friend std::string repr<Ex3>(Ex3 const&) { ... }`) doesn't it? (And that template needs to be defined or at least declared before this.)

Comment: @j_random: Nope, all the code is valid and standard as-is; literally copy into a file (after appropriate #includes) and compile it: http://codepad.org/v45tt46L. (That repr isn't a template, btw, but if it was, it wouldn't need that extra syntax either, just like Ex1's swap doesn't need it.)

Comment: Whoops, I somehow missed that you gave an in-place definition for `repr()` -- yes, that's totally valid.  But if you had instead given just a declaration, with your "fallback" template definition and an appropriate specialisation declared beforehand, then the standard requires (14.5.3) that your friend declaration use either a *template-id* (e.g. `friend std::string repr<Ex3>(...);`) or a *qualified-id* (e.g. `friend std::string N::repr(...);`, and put the template in namespace `N`). I found compiler support to be very suspect in my tests unfortunately...

Comment: @j_random: Except I'm *not* specializing. I couldn't find a reason why it's important or necessary, so I'm giving examples of *overloading*.

Comment: Yes I understand that, and agree overloading is appropriate. My 1st comment was a misunderstanding (sorry); my 2nd comment was a quibble with the final part of your prior comment: "(That repr isn't a template, btw, but if it was, it wouldn't need that extra syntax either, just like Ex1's swap doesn't need it.)" I was just pointing out that template friend syntax is weird, and awkwardly different from the syntax allowed when calling a function.

Comment: @j_random: Ah, now I see what you meant, but weird and awkward isn't required.  This is fine: `template<class T> struct Ex4 { friend string repr(Ex4 const&) { return "<Ex4>"; } };`.   It is fairly intuitive (practically the same as writing a static method, just use 'friend') and requires nothing more, and this is how I recommend to write such overloads by default (compare to Ex1's swap).

Answer (score 1):

To illustrate why function template specialization is important, consider the `std::swap` template function.  By default, `std::swap(x, y)` essentially does:

```
T temp = x;
x = y;
y = temp;
```

but this can be inefficient since it involves creating an extra copy of `x` and could do additional copying in the assignments.  This is especially bad if `x` is large (for example, if it's a `std::vector` with many elements).  Additionally, each of the above lines could fail and throw exceptions, potentially leaving `x` and `y` in bad, inconsistent states.

To address this, many classes provide their own `swap` methods (including `std::vector`) that instead swap the pointers to their internal data.  This is more efficient and can be guaranteed to never fail.

But now you have a case where you can use `std::swap(x, y)` on some types but need to call `x.swap(y)` on other types.  This is confusing, and it's bad for templates since they wouldn't be able to swap two objects in a generic, consistent way.

But `std::swap` can be *specialized* so that it calls `x.swap(y)` when called on specific types.  That means you then can use `std::swap` everywhere and (hopefully) expect it to be well-behaved.

Comment: A little narrow because the standard explicitly forbids overloading std::swap while explicitly allowing specializations (which leaves your own templates out in the cold as you can't partially specialize for them).  The solution is to consistently use non-member swap functions (e.g. defined as friends), a `using std::swap;` using-declaration, and invoking ADL (Argument Dependent Lookup) with `swap(a, b)` (note no "std::" in front)---this result is more flexible and more generic for current C++ than specializing std::swap.

Comment: Ah, right, actually specializing `std::swap` for `std::vector` this way would require partial specialization.  Argh.