# Are re-initialized classes in the same memory location as the initial class?

Tags: c++

From this question

[Shortest and best way to "reinitialize"/clean a class instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2664031/c-shortest-and-best-way-to-reinitialize-clean-a-class-instance)

The answer to "Shortest and best way to “reinitialize”/clean a class instance" is

```
myUsedInstance = myClass();
```

Now my question is: Is it guaranteed that the memory address is the same after re-initializing? That is, if I have a pointer `myClass*` that points to `myUsedInstance`, will that pointer correctly point to the newly initialized object or is there anything I have to be careful of?

Comment: Slightly related warning: if you do use placement new (as suggested by one of the answers in the linked question), *then* you need to "clean" your pointers with `std::launder` (at least with C++17)

Comment: this is just an assignment, no more than invoke a member function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The assignment does not change the old object's identity, all pointers and references to it remain valid.

Comment: Might want to also note that such an assignment relies on the class having both a working assignment operator and a constructor that can be called with no arguments.   It won't compile otherwise.

Comment: @Peter If it doesn't even compile, we certainly don't have a problem with pointer invalidation. I don't think that's what this question is about, your remark seems to fall into the scope of the linked Q/A instead.