# What is the proper way to declare a specialization of a template for another template type?

Tags: c++, templates

The usual definition for a specialization of a template function is something like this:

```
class Foo {
    [...]
};

namespace std {
    template<>
    void swap(Foo& left, Foo& right) {
        [...]
    }
} // namespace std
```

But how do you properly define the specialization when the type it's specialized on is itself a template? Here's what I've got:

```
template <size_t Bits>
class fixed {
    [...]
};

namespace std {
    template<size_t Bits>
    void swap(fixed<Bits>& left, fixed<Bits>& right) {
        [...]
    }
} // namespace std
```

Is this the right way to declare `swap`? It's supposed to be a specialization of the template function `std::swap`, but I can't tell whether the compiler is seeing it as such, or whether it thinks that it's an overload of it or something.

Comment: Sorry, I believe you're mistaken on this one. Specializations of template functions are explicitly allowed in namespace std.

Comment: You're right "A program may add template specializations for any standard library template to namespace std." Thanks for making me check.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your solution isn't a template specialization, but an overload of a function in the std namespace, which is "undefined behavior" per the c++ standard.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223245/overloading-global-swap-for-user-defined-type) is exactly your question.

Scott Meyers discusses this in Effective C++, and there is a followup thread on [usenet's comp.lang.c++](https://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.c++/browse_frm/thread/fe3ab164f30582db/0825b023d8854386?lnk=st&q+++&rnum=1&pli=1#0825b023d8854386).

- He suggests that you define it in fixed's own namespace.
- Make sure 'fixed' is in a namespace.
- Don't prefix calls to swap with 'std::'.
- Let [Koenig (a.k.a. argument dependent) lookup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_dependent_name_lookup) find the right swap function.

If you're seeing compilation errors when trying to define this in namespace std, it's likely due to your unfortunate choice of class names :)  When within `namespace std` "fixed" is being seen as `std::fixed`, the floating point precision operator.

Comment: The actual name is `fixed_integer`, I shortened it for the question. But if I declare it in a different namespace, won't all of the functions in the `std` namespace fail to call the right one? And don't most uses of `std::swap` specify the `std` namespace?

Comment: Added a wikipedia link which describes ADL for the swap use case.
Koenig lookup says that calls to non-namespace-qualified swap(N::arg1, N::arg2) will use the namespace of the arguments to determine a better fit than std::swap.  Most code I've seen doesn't explicitly call std::swap.  Prefer the "using std::swap" approach.

Comment: @Head Geek: std lib implementations _should_ use Koenig lookup for `std::swap()`, so they pick up user-defined overloads. I'm not sure they do this, though.

Answer (score 3):

Partial specializations of function templates are not allowed, so the template for `fixed<Bits>` declares a new overload, not a specialization.

This doesn't matter, though, since a call like `std::swap(a, b)` will just choose the best matching function. It doesn't require that the function is a specialization of the generic `std::swap` template. If the best matching function is a overload instead of a specialization, the overload will be called.

Answer (score 2):

Syntactically your "specialization" is done correctly. However, as others already noted, it is not really a partial specialization but a function overload. Function templates don't support partial specialization.

It is worth noting though that adding anything to namespace `std` is prohibited by the language specification (see 17.4.3.1/1). I understand why you insisted on doing it in `std` specifically, since you were trying to partially specialize `std::swap`. Since your `swap` is really an overload and not a specialization, you can safely do it outside `std`, within the same namespace that contains yor `fixed`. Argument-dependent name lookup ("Koenig lookup") should make sure that your `swap` is found by name lookup when applied to arguments of type `fixed` (unless the calling code explicitly refers to `std::swap` instead of just `swap`).

Answer (score -4):

A template parameter cannot be declared with a value that is not determined until run-time.  To use numbers for a template parameter, it needs to be a 'const' so it can be resolved at compile-time:

```
template <const size_t Bits> 
class fixed { 
    [...] 
}; 

namespace std { 
    template<const size_t Bits> 
    void swap(fixed<Bits>& left, fixed<Bits>& right) { 
        [...] 
    } 
} // namespace std
```

Comment: Eh? A template parameter has to be a compile-time constant, but I've never had any problem declaring it without the `const`. Not even a warning.