# error: constructor is protected within this context

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class Base{
    private:
        int a;
    protected:
        Base(){};
        virtual ~Base(){};
};
class Derived:private Base{
    private:
        int b;
    public:
        Derived(){};
        ~Derived(){};
        void test(){
            Base world;
        };

};

int main(){
}
```

inherit.cc|7 col 3| error: ‘Base::Base()’ is protected
inherit.cc|17 col 9| error: within this context
inherit.cc|8 col 11| error: ‘virtual Base::~Base()’ is protected
inherit.cc|17 col 9| error: within this context

But why?

And why this is correct?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class Base{
    private:
        int a;
    protected:
        Base(){};
        virtual ~Base(){};
        void test2(){};
};
class Derived:private Base{
    private:
        int b;
    public:
        Derived(){};
        ~Derived(){};
        void test(){
            test2();
        };

};

int main(){
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [One question about protected constructor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2393325/one-question-about-protected-constructor)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first example you create an object of `Base` in method `test()` of `Derived` class.

In second example you access the method `test2()` which is `protected` in `Base` & `Derived` derives from it `private`ly.

Note the rule for access specifiers of a class:

> `Protected` Access specifier means that the members declared as `Protected` are accessible from outside the class BUT only in a class derived from it.

In case of `private` Inheritance:

> All Public members of the Base Class become Private Members of the Derived class &
>   All Protected members of the Base Class become Private Members of the Derived Class.

In example 1,
Eventhough, `Derived` derives from `Base`, it can have access to protected members of `Base` only for the `Base` of the `Derived` object whose member function(`test()`) is being called not any other `Base` class object.
Given that you cannot create a `Base` object.

In example 2,
`test2()` is called on the object whose member function(`test()`) is being called, As noted above `Derived` class has access to `protected` members of `Base` for the `Base` of the `Derived` object whose member function is being called and hence `test2()` can be called.

Good Read:
[What are access specifiers? Should I inherit with private, protected or public?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5447498/what-are-access-specifiers-should-i-inherit-with-private-protected-or-public)

Comment: @tinybit: Please read the explanation carefully, *Eventhough, Derived derives from Base, **it can have access to protected members of Base only for the Base of the Derived object whose member function(test()) is being called not any other Base class object.***

Answer (score 0):

In `void Derived::test()` you try to create instance of Base class. Because of nothing said about arguments - it try to call Base default constructor, but it's `protected` - not `public`.

Also at the end of `Derived::test()` will be called destructor, but it also protected. So you cannot create instance of `Base` class with such modifiers for constructor and destructor

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class Base{
    private:
        int a;
    protected:
        Base(){}
        Base(int a) : a(a) {}
        virtual ~Base(){}
        void test2(){}
};

class Derived:private Base{
    private:
        int b;
        Derived(int b) : Base(b) {};
    public:
        Derived() : Base() {}; // uses protected constructor
        ~Derived(){};
        Base* test(){
            new Derived(-1); // uses the other protected constructor
        };

};
```

Comment: Can you add some plain text to make clear what the code means and to structure your answer?