# Access to protected constructor of base class

Tags: c++, oop, language-lawyer

A derived class can call a protected base class constructor in its *ctor-initializer*, but only for its own base class subobject, and not elsewhere:

```
class Base {
  protected:
    Base() {}
};

class Derived : Base {
  Base b;
  public:
    Derived(): Base(),    // OK
               b() {      // error
        Base b2;          // error
    }
};
```

What does the standard say about this? Here is [class.protected]/1:

> An additional access check beyond those described earlier in Clause 11 is applied when a non-static data
>   member or non-static member function is a protected member of its naming class (11.2) As described
>   earlier, access to a protected member is granted because the reference occurs in a friend or member of some
>   class `C`. If the access is to form a pointer to member (5.3.1), the *nested-name-specifier* shall denote `C` or a
>   class derived from `C`. All other accesses involve a (possibly implicit) object expression (5.2.5). In this case,
>   the class of the object expression shall be `C` or a class derived from `C`. [ *Example:* ...

Is there an object expression involved when calling a constructor? There isn't, is there? So where in the standard is access control for protected base class constructors described?

Comment: Related/duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2393325

Comment: Interestingly, constructors are supposed to have no names [class.ctor], *access control* should not apply to them ;) (as well as name lookup)

Comment: @dyp, I think the OP understands the behavior. He's searching for evidence in the standard that clearly explain the behavior. The link you posted doesn't have any answers that point to any relevant places in the standard, at least not that I saw any.

Comment: @RSahu I know, but that doesn't make it less related/less of a duplicate. Answers to *this* question also apply to the other question. I didn't close this as a duplicate, did I?

Answer (score 3):

The `protected` access only applies to parent members *of your own current object type*. You don't get public access to the protected members of *other* objects of the parent type. In your example you only get access to the default base contructor as part of a `Derived`, not when it's a standalone object as `b`.

Let's break down the quote you posted from the standard (11.4/1). We'll assume that `C` in the standard corresponds to your `Derived` class:

> An additional access check beyond those described earlier in Clause 11
>   is applied when a non-static data member or non-static member function
>   is a protected member of its naming class (11.2).

So the base class constructor is effectively a `non-static member function` of its naming class (`B`) here, so this clause applies so far.

> As described earlier, access to a protected member is granted because
>   the reference occurs in a friend or member of some class C.

Member (constructor) of `C` so we're still good here.

> If the access is to form a pointer to member (5.3.1), the
>   nested-name-specifier shall denote C or a class derived from C.

This is *not* a pointer to member so this doesn't apply.

> All other accesses involve a (possibly implicit) object expression
>   (5.2.5).

The standard then asserts that all other possible accesses must involve an object expression.

> In this case, the class of the object expression shall be C or a class
>   derived from C.

Finally the standard states that the class of the expression must be `C` or a further derived class. In this case your expression `Base()` is in fact a `C`, calling the parent constructor (think about it as `this->Base()`. The expression `b` is clearly of type `Base` (that's the explicitly declared type of the member `b`, think about `this->b->Base()`). Now we do the check: Is `Base` a `C` or child of `C`? It is not, so the code is not legal.

Comment: I see that, but where in the standard is this specified?

Comment: @Brian: you should move that comment to the question. otherwise the question is a duplicate.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf The question asks "what does the standard say about this", but I edited it anyway to reiterate.

Answer (score 1):

C++11 §11.2/5:

> **”**
>   A member `m` is accessible at the point *R* when named in class `N` if
>
> - `m` as a member of `N` is public, or
> - `m` as a member of `N` is private, and *R* occurs in a member or friend of class `N`, or
> - `m` as a member of `N` is protected, and *R* occurs in a member or friend of class `N`,
>     or in a member or friend of a class `P` derived
>     from `N`, where `m` as a member of `P` is public, private, or protected, or
> - there exists a base class `B` of `N` that is accessible at *R*,
>     and `m` is accessible at *R* when named in class `B`.

For your constructor invocation

```
Base b2;
```

the 3<sup>rd</sup> point above applies. `m` is the `Base` constructor. `N`, the naming class, is `Base`. `m` as a member of `Base` is protected, and the declaration occurs in a member of class `Derived` derived from `Base`, but it's not the case that the `Base` constructor as a member of `Derived` is public, private or protected: it’s simply not a member of `Derived`, constructors are not implicitly inherited.

I think the language “is public, private, or protected” is pretty awkward; I can only surmise that it’s the result of some evolution of this paragraph.

I have yet to find an explanation of how formally the protected `Base` constructor is accessible in a member initializer list in `Derived`, but then I just started looking at this for this question.

---

*Update*: I fail to find any language in the standard pertaining to access to constructors in an initializer list, and I fail to find any Defect Report about it. It’s quite possibly a defect.

Comment: Ah, the `&rdquo;` has a meaning, I'm sorry.

Comment: @dyp: thanks for the edit, I think it's important that quotes be very faithful to the original. unrelated: looking elsewhere, googling, i think [IBM's documentation](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/ratdevz/v8r5/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.tpf.toolkit.compilers.doc%2Fref%2Flangref_os390%2Fcbclr21019.htm) can be difficult to refer to as authoritative, since it includes examples with **`void main`** :(

Comment: *"It’s quite possibly a defect."* It you want to bring that to the committee's attention, also note that constructors are supposed to have no names [class.ctor]/1. Therefore, I guess that a lot of the text about *accessibility of names* should not apply to them. (But then again, constructors can be found by name lookup [class.qual]/2, so this might be another, unrelated defect.)

Answer (score 0):

This is [CWG issue 1883](https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/1883.html). The wording is indeed not clear, but the missing wording that needs to be added to the standard has not yet been drafted.