# Calling potential variadic base class protected member functions

Tags: c++, c++20, crtp

For context: I'm constructing a CRTP Mixin for my derived class.

Now I want to call all protected base class member functions if they exist.
I want to have the base class member functions not exposed to the user.

For this I have the following code:

```cpp
struct A {
   protected:
    void fooImpl() { std::cout << "A::fooImpl"; }
};

struct C {};

template <typename... T>
struct B : T... {
    void foo() {
        auto visitor = [](auto& s) {
            if constexpr (requires { s.fooImpl(); }) 
                s.fooImpl();
        };
        (visitor(static_cast<T&>(*this)), ...);
    }
};

int main() {
    B<A, C> b;
    b.foo();
    return 0;
}
```

[Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/xvGWhz3bx)
This code does not call the `fooImpl` from `C` (as expected) and also not the one from `A`.

I assume this is due to the `static_cast`, which removes the `protected` visibility of `fooImpl`. **Is this expected?** I assume so when following the discussion from [Access to protected constructor of base class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24636234/access-to-protected-constructor-of-base-class), which also applies to my case, doesn't it?

I have two solutions, which I think are **not** elegant.

1. Going the CRTP path and forward the derived class to the base to make derived a friend.

```cpp
template <typename S>
struct A {
    friend S;

   private:
    void fooImpl() { std::cout << "A::fooImpl"; }
};

template <typename S>
struct C {};

template <template <typename> class... T>
struct B : T<B<T...>>... {
    void foo() {
        auto visitor = [](auto& s) {
            if constexpr (requires { s.fooImpl(); }) 
                s.fooImpl();
        };
        (visitor(static_cast<T<B<T...>>&>(*this)), ...);
    }
};
```

[Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/bnf9vd57r)
This works but I wonder if there is a better way. I also have to refactor all the template signature of my class, which is not so nice.

2. Hiding the base class `foo`s by calling convention and rename `fooImpl` to `foo`

```cpp
struct A {
   public:
    void foo() { std::cout << "A::foo"; }
};

struct C {};

template <typename... T>
struct B : T... {
    void foo() {
        auto visitor = [](auto& s) {
            if constexpr (requires { s.foo(); }) 
                s.foo();
        };
        (visitor(static_cast<T&>(*this)), ...);
    }
};
```

[Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/K6njxG1T5)

This also works but I also think maybe I have overengineered this. Anyway the base class member function are now also hidden to the user.
**Is there a nicer way to achieve this?** Thanks!

**EDIT**: Refactor of the last question. Is there are more modern way to achieve this with less boilder-plate?

Comment: *"Is there a nicer way to achieve this?..."* Nicer/better means different things to different people.

Comment: Thats right. What is also not very precise but I'm wondering if there is a more modern C++ solution with less boiler-plate.

Comment: I think you have to do something like this anyway. There is no way to make a concept that checks if A implements foo when foo is protected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of checking if `A` implements a protected member function in your concept, you could check if `this->A::fooImpl()` is a valid statement for `B`.

To do this, capture `this` in your visitor lambda:

```cpp
template <typename... T>
struct B : T... {
    void foo() {
        auto visitor = [this] <typename U>(U&) {
            if constexpr (requires { this->U::fooImpl(); }) this->U::fooImpl();
        };
        (visitor(static_cast<T&>(*this)), ...); // note: argument just passed for template argument deduction
    }
};
```

https://godbolt.org/z/s5Yohd9sM

Note that if you don't add `U&` as an argument to your lambda, the fold expression becomes `(visitor.template operator()<T>(), ...);` which is a bit awkward IMHO. Having a private `template <typename U> void call_base_foo_impl()` in `B` instead of the lambda might improve readability as well.

Comment: you can capture `this` instead passing it by argument.

Comment: You can do this and iterate over the `T...` pack directly: `([&]{ if constexpr (requires { this->T::fooImpl(); }) this->T::fooImpl();  }(), ...)`

Comment: @MarekR The `this` is captured, it's passed purely for template argument deduction purposes (it could be turned into a `U*` parameter and `static_cast<T*>(nullptr)` could be used instead i guess, but it doesn't really matter)

Comment: This is what I meant by a more elegant solution. Refactoring it from a lambda to a a full function where only `T` has to be passed as a template is then perfect.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is you need scope operator instead casting `this` to respective type. When using cast pointer you need public access.
I've got nice C++17 solution (C++17 since I used fold expression, it is should be easy to tweak it to C++11):

```cpp
template <typename... T>
struct B : T... {
    void foo()
    {
        (invokeFooImpl<T>(1), ...);
    }

private:
    template <typename Base>
    auto invokeFooImpl(int) -> decltype(Base::fooImpl())
    {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n';
        Base::fooImpl();
    }

    template <typename Base>
    auto invokeFooImpl(char)
    {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n';
    }
};
```

https://godbolt.org/z/avExz4M9s

Or C++20 version without lamda:

```cpp
template <typename... T>
struct B : T... {
    void foo()
    {
        (invokeFooImpl<T>(), ...);
    }

private:
    template <typename Base>
    auto invokeFooImpl()
    {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n';
        if constexpr (requires { this->Base::fooImpl(); }) Base::fooImpl();
    }
};
```

https://godbolt.org/z/hvEb83zro

Comment: This is what I meant by a more elegant solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you find it nicer, but here you go:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

struct A {
protected:
    void foo()
    {
        std::cout << "A::foo" << std::endl;
    }
};

struct C {};

template <typename... T>
struct B : private T...
{
    void foo()
    {
        // [[maybe_unused]] auto list = std::initializer_list<bool>{ (callFoo<T>(), true)...}; // pre-17                                                                                                           
        (callFoo<T>(), ...); // fold-expression
    }

private:
    
    template <typename U>
    void callFoo()
    {
        if constexpr (requires {U::foo(); })
        {
            U::foo();
        }
    }

};

int main()
{
    {
        B<A, C> b;
        b.foo();
    }
    {
        B<> b;
        b.foo();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `std::initializer_list` trick was to expand for pre C++17, since, we have simply `(callFoo<T>(), ...);`.

Comment: @Jarod42 That's right, thanks. Old habits... I've updated the answer.