# c++ Inheritance with templates and visibility

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, visibility

I don't understand att all inheritance with templates..

```
template <typename T> 
class Mere 
{ 
protected:
    Mere();
}; 

class Fille2 : public Mere<int>
{ 
protected:
    Fille2(){
        Mere();
    }
}; 


int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    return 0;
}
```

Why do I have this error?

```
main.cpp:22:5: error: 'Mere<T>::Mere() [with T = int]' is protected
Mere();
```

And all works when I put "Mere()" in public? I can't have "protected" functions for my class "Mere"? Why?

Comment: this is not how you invoke constructors of a parent class in c++... see [here](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/DtiZ3q60YyVytvju) on how it can be done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can call the base class constructor, even if it is `protected`. Here is the correct syntax:

```
class Fille2 : public Mere<int>
{ 
protected:
    Fille2(): Mere() {
    }
};
```

For a detailed discussion, see [Why is protected constructor raising an error this this code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2393325/why-is-protected-constructor-raising-an-error-this-this-code)