# How to call a parameter constructor of a class that contains a copy constructor as private,in c++?

Tags: c++, constructor, copy-constructor

I have a class that consists of a parameterized constructor which I need to call while creating an object. The class also contains a private copy constructor restricting to create an object to it. Now how to call the paramter constructor of this class. I think we can create a pointer reference to the class. But how to call the parameter constructor using the reference?

**My Program:**

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

class ABase
{
protected:
    ABase(string str) {
        cout<<str<<endl;
        cout<<"ABase Constructor"<<endl;
    }
    ~ABase() {
    cout<<"ABASE Destructor"<<endl;
    }
private:
    ABase( const ABase& );
    const ABase& operator=( const ABase& );
};


int main( void )
{
    ABase *ab;//---------How to call the parameter constructor using this??

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax you need is `ABase *ab = new ABase(foo);` where `foo` is either a `std::string` instance or something that `std::string` can take on construction, such as a `const char[]` literal, e.g. `"Hello"`.

Don't forget to call `delete` to release the memory.

(Alternatively you could write `ABase ab(foo)` if you don't need a pointer type.)

Comment: *Personally*, I would prefer to see `const auto ab = std::make_unique<ABase>(foo);`  (In other words use std::unique_ptr, and let `make_unique` hide the `new` for you.)

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this. Because your ctor is `protected`. Please see (not related with your state, but only to learn more): [Why is protected constructor raising an error this this code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2393325/why-is-protected-constructor-raising-an-error-this-this-code)