# cannot print using ostream but can by using cout?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, protected, ostream

Let this be the example code:

```
object o1(//parameters);
object o2(//parameters);
object o3(//parameters);
object *v[3];

using std::cout; //video output
ofstream of;     //save on file

//let's suppose

v[0]=&o1;
v[1]=&o2;
v[2]=&o3;
for (int i=0;i<3;i++) {
    v[i]->view(cout);
    v[i]->save(of);
}
```

view function is just a video print function of parameters of the class, while save function saves parameters of the class on a file. The question is, if i declare `std::ostream;` and `ostream os;` why can't I use `v[i]->view(os)` to have video output? If I use `v[i]->view(os)` it says:

`'std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::basic_ostream() [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]' is protected`

And while that's true for video output, for the saving function it is not, it works, just as intended in the code. Can someone explain? sorry if i made it long

Comment: Can we see the code that doesn't work, including how `view` is defined ([mcve] please)?

Comment: None of the code you've shown mentions `std::ostream`. The error message is coming from some other code. Post **that code**. But the problem is fairly clear from the description. `std::ostream` is intended to be used as a base class for output streams. `std::ostream os;` is not intended to work, and the compiler rightly complains.

Comment: `std::ostream` is just an interface class, you need a subclass (such as `ofstream` or `ostringstream`) to do something useful. The error you got is a message that only subclasses can invoke the `ostream` constructor, which hints at "look for a subclass".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is protected constructor raising an error this this code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2393325/why-is-protected-constructor-raising-an-error-this-this-code)

Comment: btw `std::cout` is an `ostream`

Comment: @user463035818 -- white that's true, it's not helpful. `std::cout` is part of the implementation, and it can rely on internal details of the standard library implementation that ordinary programmers cannot.

Comment: @PeteBecker maybe not that helpful to find a solution, but helpful to fix the misunderstanding that manifests in the question title ;)

Comment: Please provide the function declaration of `object::view` and `object::save`.

Answer (score 0):

### The issues:

1) If the `view` function is defined as:

```
void view(std::ostream output, std::string text) // (1)
{
    output << text;
}
```

And used:

```
view(std::cout, "Hello, World!"); // (2)
```

Then an error message is given by the compiler:

In MSVC:

> `error C2280: 'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::basic_ostream(const std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &)': attempting to reference a deleted function`

GCC:

> `error: use of deleted function 'std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::basic_ostream(const std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]'`

Clang:

> `error: call to deleted constructor of 'std::ostream' (aka 'basic_ostream<char>')`

---

2) For the declaration

```
std::ostream os;
```

The following error message is displayed:

MSVC:

> `error C2512: 'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>': no appropriate default constructor available`

GCC:

> `error: 'std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::basic_ostream() [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]' is protected within this context`

Clang:

> `error: calling a protected constructor of class 'std::basic_ostream<char>'`

---

### The reason:

This is all according to the specification of [std::basic_ostream](http://http://eel.is/c++draft/ostream)

There is no definition for a default constructor - so a variable of the type `std::ostream` cannot be created, without specific constructor parameters.

And as C++ Reference says about the [std::basic_ostream copy constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/basic_ostream):

> The copy constructor is protected, and is deleted. Output streams are not copyable.

---

### Explanation:

1) So the problem is that in `(2)` the parameter `std::cout` is been passed to a function which is defined in `(1)` to copy the `std::ostream` to the variable `output`.

But the definition of the class says that the copy constructor cannot be used, so the compiler gives an error message.

2) In the case of creating the variable `os` - it is not giving any constructor parameters, there is no default constructor, so the compiler gives an error message.

---

### How to fix this?

1) In the declaration of the function change the definition to take a reference (`&`) of `std::ostream` as a parameter:

```
void view(std::ostream& output, std::string text) // (1)
```

This allows it to use the original object instead of making a copy (which the copy is not allowed).

---

2) If a variable is required, then also a reference should be used;

```
std::ostream& out = std::cout;
```