# overload resolution in implement of boost::bind

Tags: c++, boost, overload-resolution

```
// bind.hpp
template< class A1 > class list1: private storage1< A1 >
{

    template<class R, class F, class A> R operator()(type<R>, F & f, A & a, long)
    {
        return unwrapper<F>::unwrap(f, 0)(a[base_type::a1_]);
    }

    template<class F, class A> void operator()(type<void>, F & f, A & a, int)
    {
        unwrapper<F>::unwrap(f, 0)(a[base_type::a1_]);
    }
}
```

Why add arguments `int`/`long` in `operator()`?

If I delete these `int`/`long`, still pass compile.

Comment: The only difference between those two overloads seems to be the return type, and the last type parameter is being used as a tag type to explicitly differentiate between functions that return void and functions that return any other type.

Comment: R operator()(type<R>, F  f, A & a) and void operator()(type<void>, F  f, A & a) still work well, if I call operator()(type<void>, f, a).  Why need add a argument to do overload resolution?

Comment: You don't have to if you test them both out and it works. Normally, you don't even need the `int` overload version, as returning `void` will work properly when `T = void`; returning void is a valid expression, see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3305917/4683600.

Comment: here is my demo code. http://ideone.com/MZtwbc.  Overload resolution choose the operator()(type<R>, F  f, A & a) for non void, another for void

Comment: Because you have an overload that uses `type<void>` which is an exact match. That is also a tag. If you just want to defer a function call to another, you can just do this: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7f6c2c86768f8979

Comment: I got your idea(return void is valid).  But why boost::bind do above?  add a void overload version.