# Why is "operator void" not invoked with cast syntax?

Tags: c++, casting, operators, operator-overloading

While playing with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4030959/will-a-variablename-c-statement-be-a-no-op-at-all-times/4030983#4030983) by [user GMan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/87234/gman) I crafted the following snippet (compiled with Visual C++ 9):

```
 class Class {
 public:
     operator void() {}
 };

 Class object;
 static_cast<void>( object );
 (void)object;
 object.operator void();
```

after stepping over with the debugger I found out that casting to `void` doesn't invoke `Class::operator void()`, only the third invokation (with explicitly invoking the operator) actually invokes the operator, the two casts just do nothing.

Why is the `operator void` not invoked with the cast syntax?

Comment: I love how you always ask weird but interesting questions ;) Here is my +1.

Comment: What code would you expect to be executed *without* the cast? Actually none... why should casting change this?

Comment: @Eiko: If that was `operator int()` and I wrote `(int)object;` then `operator int()` would be invoked. Turns out this isn't the case with `operator void()`, so I asked this question.

Comment: fwiw, this is called all 3 times when compiled with llvm-gcc 4.2 (apple)

Comment: Well, not with VS C++, but with gcc here, and it gets called three times - checked with some text dumping from the operator void() implementation. Do you have actually code in that method? Maybe it's the compiler optimizing it away.

Comment: For what it's worth, Comeau gives the following warning: "Class::operator void()" will not be called for implicit or explicit conversions".

Comment: and gcc warns: `conversion to void will never use a type conversion operator`

Comment: @Eiko: I added a message box into the operator implementaton - it only shows once, so the operator is only called once.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The technical reason why is found in §12.3.2:

> A conversion function is never used to convert a (possibly cv-qualified) object to the (possibly cv-qualified) same object type (or a reference to it), to a (possibly cv-qualified) base class of that type (or a reference to it), **or to (possibly cv-qualified) void**.

The rationale is (likely) to allow §5.2.9/4 to work:

> Any expression can be explicitly converted to type “cv void.” The expression value is discarded.

`(void)expr` to suppose to do nothing for the resulting value of *any* expression, but if it called your conversion operator it wouldn't be discarding anything. So they ban the use of `operator void` in conversions.

---

Why not make it ill-formed to have the conversion-type-id be `void`? Who knows, but keep in mind it's not *totally* useless:

```
struct foo
{
    operator void()
    {
        std::cout << "huh?" << std::endl;
    }

};

typedef void (foo::*void_function)();

foo f;
void_function func = &foo::operator void;

(f.*func)(); // prints "huh"
f.operator void(); // also does (which you knew)
```

It is still technically potentially useful for *something*, so maybe that's rationale enough not to make it ill-formed.

Comment: *"Why not make it ill-formed to have the conversion-type-id be `void`?"* Maybe because that `void` might be hidden behind a typedef or template parameter?

Comment: @dyp, and that's the problem with being *not* _ill-formed_: unexpected behaviour: you expect the conversion operator to convert, but this one won't ever do that. Make it _ill-formed_ would help the developer of supposed template library to catch bugs early on. But, at least nowadays compilers issue the warning for this case.

Comment: @GreenScape There are use cases where you don't care that it won't be called, and with `ill-formed`, you have to generate special cases. Just like `f(future.get())` for `future<void>`.

Comment: Moreover, the standard conversion to `void` should outcompete any user-defined conversion for the purpose.