# How do you loop over a parameter pack using a pack expansion?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates, pack-expansion

I am trying to learn variadic templates and functions. I can't understand why this code doesn't compile:

```cpp
template<typename T>
static void bar(T t) {}

template<typename... Args>
static void foo2(Args... args)
{
    (bar(args)...);
}

int main()
{
    foo2(1, 2, 3, "3");
    return 0;    
}
```

When I compile it fails with the error:

> Error C3520: 'args': parameter pack must be expanded in this context

(in function `foo2`).

Comment: What if `Args` was empty?

Answer (score 158, accepted):

One of the places where a pack expansion can occur is inside a *braced-init-list*. You can take advantage of this by putting the expansion inside the initializer list of a dummy array:

```
template<typename... Args>
static void foo2(Args &&... args)
{
    int dummy[] = { 0, ( (void) bar(std::forward<Args>(args)), 0) ... };
}
```

To explain the content of the initializer in more detail:

```
{ 0, ( (void) bar(std::forward<Args>(args)), 0) ... };
  │       │       │                        │     │
  │       │       │                        │     └─// pack expand the whole thing 
  │       │       │                        │   
  │       │       └─// perfect forwarding  └─// comma operator
  │       │
  │       └─// cast to void to ensure that regardless of bar()'s return type
  │         // the built-in comma operator is used rather than an overloaded one
  │
  └─// ensure that the array has at least one element so that we don't try to make an
    // illegal 0-length array when args is empty
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0c0950c1c2225b6f).

An important advantage of expanding in `{}` is that it guarantees left-to-right evaluation.

---

With C++17 [fold expressions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold), you can just write

```
((void) bar(std::forward<Args>(args)), ...);
```

Comment: One variant I've seen is `using expander = int[]; expander{...};` because then the array variable has no name, and it becomes blatantly obvious to the compiler that the array doesn't need to me created or used.

Comment: What's the second `0` for? The one just after the comma operator

Comment: @AaronMcDaid So that the type of the whole expression is `int` and matches the array's element type.

Comment: I have noticed that one can write an `operator void ()` (yes, mad, I know). But no, I'm not really saying that casting to `void` is a bad idea. Just having fun thinking about crazy stuff that can happen when trying to expand a pack with minimal side effects

Comment: @AaronMcDaid [`(void)` never invokes `operator void()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4031228/why-is-operator-void-not-invoked-with-cast-syntax) (thankfully).

Comment: Last time I tried with GCC, it insisted on calling `operator void` when you casted to `void`. Therefore, I always write `(foo, void(), 0)...`, to have it work also for GCC.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb [GCC hasn't been doing it since 4.8, I think](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=54165). The issue with `void()` is that it still triggers overload resolution, which may cause template instantiations that lead to hard errors.

Comment: @T.C. it triggers overload resolution, but it does not really overload-resolve. Because if either the left or right operand of the comma operator is of type `void`, then the builtin comma operator is used (there's a special case for this). Can you please show an example that has an hard error because of this style of the void trick?

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb Right, but the way it works is that you assemble a candidate set, find that nothing is viable, and then default to to the builtin, and the first step can trigger a hard error: https://godbolt.org/g/31hCVe

Comment: @T.C. I was in the impression that if one of the operands is void, then there are no user defined candidates. Looking again, I see that I was wrong.

Comment: @T.C.: I added [a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58588748) to this Q&A that you most definitely have some good input to, if you have the time and interest.

Comment: @MooingDuck It is already blatantly obvious to the compiler; using `expander{...}` makes it obvious to the programmer as well.

Answer (score 43):

Parameter packs can only be expanded in a strictly-defined list of contexts, and operator `,` is not one of them. In other words, it's not possible to use pack expansion to generate an expression consisting of a series of subexpressions delimited by operator `,`.

The rule of thumb is "Expansion can generate a *list* of `,`-separated patterns where `,` is a *list* delimiter." Operator `,` does not construct a list in the grammar sense.

To call a function for each argument, you can use recursion (which is the primary tool in the variadic template programmer's box):

```
template <typename T>
void bar(T t) {}

void foo2() {}

template <typename Car, typename... Cdr>
void foo2(Car car, Cdr... cdr)
{
  bar(car);
  foo2(cdr...);
}

int main()
{
  foo2 (1, 2, 3, "3");
}
```

[**Live example**](http://ideone.com/6vrRTD)

Comment: damn, you just bet me to answering this *shakes fist* but you should probably add perfect forwarding to your answer; that's also a "primary tool in the variadic template programmer's box".

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know about recursion implementation. I just want to find workaround to compile code without recursion and new function.

Comment: @ViacheslavDronov seeing as though you're using templates: you already have a crap-load of functions being generated by the compiler, why not add one on to that list?

Comment: @CoffeeandCode I officially give you permission to copy my answer and expand on it with adding and explaining perfect forwarding.

Comment: You can easily do the expansion with a dummy array. `int dummy[] = { 0, ((void) bar(std::forward<Args>(args)),0)... };`.

Comment: @T.C. That's a great trick, haven't seen that one before. I feel you should actually turn this into an answer.

Answer (score 19):

[**SHAMELESS COPY <sub>[approved by its source]</sub>**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25680524/2069064)

Parameter packs can only be expanded in a strictly-defined list of contexts, and operator `,` is not one of them. In other words, it's not possible to use pack expansion to generate an expression consisting of a series of subexpressions delimited by operator `,`.

The rule of thumb is "Expansion can generate a list of `,`-separated patterns where `,` is a list delimiter." Operator `,` does not construct a list in the grammar sense.

To call a function for each argument, you can use recursion (which is the primary tool in the variadic template programmer's box):

```
#include <utility>

template<typename T>
void foo(T &&t){}

template<typename Arg0, typename Arg1, typename ... Args>
void foo(Arg0 &&arg0, Arg1 &&arg1, Args &&... args){
    foo(std::forward<Arg0>(arg0));
    foo(std::forward<Arg1>(arg1), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

auto main() -> int{
    foo(1, 2, 3, "3");
}
```

---

**USEFUL NON-COPIED INFO**

Another thing you probably haven't seen in this answer is use of the `&&` specifier and `std::forward`. In C++, the `&&` specifier can mean one of 2 things: rvalue-references, or universal references.

I won't go into rvalue-references, but to somebody working with variadic templates; universal references are a god-send.

**Perfect Forwarding**

One of the uses of `std::forward` and universal references are perfect forwarding of types to other functions.

In your example, if we pass an `int&` to `foo2` it will be automatically demoted to `int` because of the signature of the generated `foo2` function after template deduction and if you wanted to then forward this `arg` to another function that would modify it by reference, you will get undesired results (the variable won't be changed) because `foo2` will be passing a reference to the temporary created by passing an `int` to it. To get around this, we specify a forwarding function to take **any** type of **reference** to a variable (rvalue **or** lvalue). Then, to be sure that we pass the exact type passed in the forwarding function we use `std::forward`, then and **only** then do we allow the demoting of types; because we are now at the point where it matters most.

If you need to, read more on [universal references](http://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers) and [perfect forwarding](http://thbecker.net/articles/rvalue_references/section_07.html); Scott Meyers is pretty great as a resource.

Answer (score 12):

The C++17 solution to this is really close to your expected code:

```
template<typename T>
static void bar(T t) {}

template<typename... Args>
static void foo2(Args... args) {
    (bar(args), ...);
}

int main() {
    foo2(1, 2, 3, "3");
    return 0;    
}
```

This expand the pattern with the comma operator between every expression

```
// imaginary expanded expression
(bar(1), bar(2), bar(3), bar("3"));
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `make_tuple` for pack expansion as it introduces a context where the `,` sequence produced by an expansion is valid

```
make_tuple( (bar(std::forward<Args>(args)), 0)... );
```

Now, I suspect the unused/unnamed/temporary tuple of zeroes that's produced is detectable by the compiler and optimized away.

[**Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/15a21eae273483af)

Comment: This doesn't make any guarantees about which order `bar` is invoked in

Answer (score 1):

This is a full example, based on the answers here.

Example to reproduce `console.log` as seen in JavaScript:

```
Console console;
console.log("bunch", "of", "arguments");
console.warn("or some numbers:", 1, 2, 3);
console.error("just a prank", "bro");
```

Filename e.g. `js_console.h`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

class Console {
protected:
    template <typename T>
    void log_argument(T t) {
        std::cout << t << " ";
    }
public:
    template <typename... Args>
    void log(Args&&... args) {
        int dummy[] = { 0, ((void) log_argument(std::forward<Args>(args)),0)... };
        cout << endl;
    }

    template <typename... Args>
    void warn(Args&&... args) {
        cout << "WARNING: ";
        int dummy[] = { 0, ((void) log_argument(std::forward<Args>(args)),0)... };
        cout << endl;
    }

    template <typename... Args>
    void error(Args&&... args) {
        cout << "ERROR: ";
        int dummy[] = { 0, ((void) log_argument(std::forward<Args>(args)),0)... };
        cout << endl;
    }
};
```