# c++11 variadic args with function default argument value

Tags: c++11, variadic-templates

I have wrapper that invokes template function N times:

```
template <std::uint16_t N, typename F, typename  ... Args>
inline typename std::result_of<F && (Args &&...)>::type retry_n(F && f, Args&& ... ax)
{
    for (auto i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        try
        {
            return std::forward<F>(f)(std::forward<Args>(ax)...);
        }
        catch (const some_except &e){ /*ignore exception for a while*/ }
    }
    throw;//re-raise
}
```

Everything works fine until I pass function with default argument:

```
int f(int a, int b, int c = 5);
.... 
retry_n<10>(f, 1, 2); // error C2198: 'bla-bla' : too few arguments for call
```

How to allow default argument be used without explicit specification?

Comment: `retry_fn<10>([](auto...x){return f(x...);}, 1, 2)`

Comment: @ᐅJohannesSchaub-litbᐊ yes it is clear workaround

Answer (score 2):

A default parameter is not part of a function signature, and does not participate in template type deduction. So whenever you pass `f` to `retry_n<>`, the type of `F` is deduced as `int(int, int, int)`, so the local `f` is of this latter type, and the default parameters is out of the process now. Your only solution is to use the function you want to test directly without having its type deduced, like in the comment of @Johannes Schaub - litb, or, if your compiler doesn't support generic lambdas (C++14), wrap it into a functor with a variadic template `operator()`

```
struct functor
{
    template<typename... T>
    int operator()(T&&... params)
    {
        return f(std::forward<T>(params)...);
    }  
};
```

and use it as

```
retry_n<10>(functor{}, 1, 2);
```

Comment: Thank you for technically correct answer. I've looking on http://stackoverflow.com/a/27687037/149818 and have some feeling that `std::enable_if_t` can be applied there

Comment: @Dewfy Hmmm, it may be, please post an answer if you find a solution, the problem is interesting.