# How to generalize this function with variadic templates c++

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

I have the following function. It converts two bindings of `T0` and `T1` to a binding of a `tuple<T0,T1>`

The function is as follows

```cpp
template<typename T0, typename T1>
typename RxBinding<std::tuple<T0,T1>>::Ptr
Combine(RxBinding<T0>::Ptr b0, RxBinding<T1>::Ptr b1)
{
    using Tuple = std::tuple<T0,T1>;
    RxBinding<Tuple>::Ptr binding = makeValueBinding(std::make_tuple(b0->Get(),b1->Get()));

    // Break the reference cycle. 
    auto bindingWeak = std::weak_ptr<RxBinding<Tuple>>(binding);

    auto s0 = b0->Subscribe([bindingWeak,b1](T0 const & v0){
        auto b = bindingWeak.lock();
        if(b)
            b->Update(std::make_tuple(v0,b1->Get()));
    });

    auto s1 = b1->Subscribe([bindingWeak,b0](T1 const & v1){
        auto b = bindingWeak.lock();
        if(b)
            b->Update(std::make_tuple(b0->Get(),v1));
    });

    auto sN =  binding->Subscribe([b0,b1](std::tuple<T0,T1> const & t){
        b0->Update(std::get<0>(t));
        b1->Update(std::get<1>(t));
    });

    binding->CleanupWith << s0 << s1 << sN;

    return binding;
}
```

Don't worry too much about what a binding is. Assume they work. I'm looking for a pattern to generalise this using C++11 variadic templates so I can have N bindings as input rather than just two and convert them to a single binding?

```cpp
template <typename ...T>
typename RxBinding<std::tuple<T...>>::Ptr
Combine( RxBinding<T>::Ptr args...) /* is this possible ?? */
{
    using Tuple = std::tuple<T...>;
    auto binding = makeValueBinding(std::make_tuple( /* what do do here with args ?? */ ));

    // Break the reference cycle. 
    RxBinding<Tuple>::Ptr bindingWeak = std::weak_ptr<RxBinding<Tuple>>(binding);

    // Make N subscriptions b0,b1,....bN with the weak reference above

    /* What to do here ?? */

    // Make the final subscription

    auto sN = binding->Subscribe([](std::tuple<T...> const & t){
        // Update the N bindings.

        /* what to do here ? */

    });

    // Add all subscriptions to the cleanup on the final binding
    /* not sure what to do here */

    return binding;
}
```

Comment: "Don't worry too much about what a binding is. Assume they work" well, how can we write a code around a "thing" that we don't know what it is, what is supposed to do and what its API is? For instance in your first example `s0` references `b1` and `s1` references `b0`. How are we supposed to know how to generalize that for an arbitrary number of `b`s?

Comment: It would be good if you could provide us a [MRE] that we can actually compile/run/debug.

Comment: What is the logic for `b1->Subscribe([bindingWeak,b0](T1 const & v1){..}`? each pair, prev/next?

Comment: Is `Combine(b0, b1, b2)` equivalent to `Combine(Combine(b0, b1), b2)` ?

Comment: @Jarod42  ``Combine(b0,b1,b2)`` would not be the same as  ``Combine(Combine(b0,b1),b2)`` as the first would generate bindings on ``tuple<T0,T1,T2>`` and the second would generate bindings on ``tuple<tuple<T0,T1>,T2>``

Comment: Think of RxBinding as a duplex channel and Combine is a multiplexor which takes N duplex channels and generates a new single duplex channel. Maybe later I'll try again with something a bit more simple to figure out the pattern. Seems a bit too vauge for SO unfortunately.

Comment: This might be close to what I'm looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45841555/map-variadic-template-arguments

Comment: Maybe also provide version with 3 argument to see the logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `RxBinding<T>::Ptr` `T` can't be deduced, as it's a non-deduced context because of nested types (see example 1) under Non-deduced contexts on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction) and [godbolt example](https://godbolt.org/z/soQvHG)), so the original example shouldn't have worked with argument deduction.  With that in mind having `typename RxBinding<Ts>::Ptr ...args` will work the same way as it did before (note the syntax having `...` before the argument name). I changed the variadic type template to `Ts` instead of `T`, to better represent that it's variadic.

With `auto binding = makeValueBinding(std::make_tuple( /* what do do here with args ?? */ ));` you can use a [pack expansion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack) with the pattern `args->Get()`, so the final line will be
`auto binding = makeValueBinding(std::make_tuple(args->Get()...));`.

Creation of the variables `s0`, `s1`, and so on is not trivial, so I'll get back to it at the end.

To make the final subscribtion, you will need to use a helper function to expand the tuple:

```
template<typename ...ArgTypes, typename ...Ts, std::size_t ...Ns>
void FinalSubscribeHelper(
    std::tuple<ArgTypes...> const &args,
    std::tuple<Ts...> const &t,
    std::index_sequence<Ns...>
)
{
    // using C++17's fold expressions (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold)
    ((std::get<Ns>(args)->Update(std::get<Ns>(t))), ...); // we use the comma operator for expansion
    return;

    // using array initializers for C++11
    using ArrayT = int[sizeof...(ArgTypes)];
    ArrayT{
        ((
            std::get<Ns>(args)->Update(std::get<Ns>(t)) // this is the pattern
        ), 0)...
    };
    return;
}
```

So the final subscribtion is

```
auto sN = binding->Subscribe([=](std::tuple<Ts...> const &t){
    // Update the N bindings.
    FinalSubscribeHelper(std::make_tuple(args...), t, std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Ts)>{});
});
```

For adding all subscriptions to the cleanup you will need another helper function:

```
template<typename BindingT, typename ...STs, typename SNT, std::size_t ...Ns>
void CleanupHelper(
    BindingT const &binding,
    std::tuple<Ts...> const &s,
    SNT const &sN
    std::index_sequence<Ns...>
)
{
    // using C++17's fold expressions (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold)
    (binding->CleanupWith << ... << std::get<Ns>(s)) << sN;
    return;

    // using array initializers for C++11
    /*
    this only works if
    binding->CleanupWith << s0 << s1 << sN;
    is equivalent to
    binding->CleanupWith << s0;
    binding->CleanupWith << s1;
    binding->CleanupWith << sN;
    */
    using ArrayT = int[sizeof...(ArgTypes)];
    ArrayT{
        ((
            binding->CleanupWith << std::get<Ns>(s)
        ), 0)...
    };
    binding->CleanupWith << sN;
    return;
}
```

So the final cleanup is
`CleanupHelper(binding, s, sN, std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Ts)>{});`.

Now get back to creating `s`. To create the callback I assume you want `Update` to be called as
`b->Update(std::make_tuple(/* bM->Get() with M = 0, 1, 2, ..., I-1 */, vI, /* bM->Get() with M = I+1, I+2, ..., N-1 */));`.  For this you need two index sequences, one from `0` to `I-1` and one from `I+1` to `N-1`.  For that let's create some type aliases to make the needed `std::index_sequence`'s.

```
template<std::size_t Offset, typename T>
struct AddOffset;

template<std::size_t Offset, std::size_t ...Ns>
struct AddOffset<Offset, std::index_sequence<Ns...>>
{
    using type = std::index_sequence<(Ns + Offset)...>;
};

template<std::size_t Offset, typename T>
using AddOffsetT = typename AddOffset<Offset, T>::type;

// this creates a std::index_sequence with the values
// Start, Start+1, Start+2, ..., End-1
template<std::size_t Start, std::size_t End>
using MakeIndexSequenceInRange = AddOffsetT<Start, std::make_index_sequence<End - Start>>;
```

To create `s` you will need a few helper functions:

```
template<typename BindingT, typename ...ArgTypes, typename VT, std::size_t ...Ns, std::size_t ...Ms>
void SubscribeCallbackHelper(
    BindingT const &b,
    std::tuple<ArgTypes...> const &args,
    VT const &v,
    std::index_sequence<Ns...>,
    std::index_sequence<Ms...>
)
{
    b->Update(std::make_tuple(std::get<Ns>(args)->Get()..., v, std::get<Ms>(args)->Get()...));
}

template<typename BindingWeakT, typename ...ArgTypes, std::size_t ...Ns>
auto CreateS(
    BindingWeakT const &bindingWeak,
    std::tuple<ArgTypes...> const &args,
    std::index_sequence<Ns...>
) -> decltype(std::make_tuple(std::get<Ns>(args)->Subscribe(std::declval<void(*)(ArgTypes const &)>())...))
// I'm not sure this decltype will work, if you have C++14 you should be able to just use auto as a return type
{
    return std::make_tuple(
        std::get<Ns>(args)->Subscribe([bindingWeak, args](ArgTypes const &v) {
            auto b = bindingWeak.lock();
            if (b)
                SubscribeCallbackHelper(b, args, v, MakeIndexSequenceInRange<0, Ns>{}, MakeIndexSequenceInRange<Ns+1, sizeof...(ArgTypes)>{});
        })
    );
}
```

So the creation of `s` will be

```
auto s = CreateS(bindingWeak, std::make_tuple(args...), std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Ts)>{});
```

Comment: Notice that `std::index_sequence` is C++14, but implementation in C++11 is available on SO and elsewhere.