# how to traverse ...args (variable length template arguments)

Tags: c++

I need to output(cout) all the args for variable length template arguments.
Thanks in advance.

```
 template <class... Args>
    void print(Args &&... args)
    {
        cout << sizeof...(args) << endl;
        //how to traverse ...args
        //expect output :1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8

    }

    int main()
    {
        print(1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8);
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Variadic template pack expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25680461/variadic-template-pack-expansion)

Comment: They can't be traversed. You can *unpack* them into other expressions

Comment: You can unpack args using following syntax `int dummy[] = { 0, ( (void) (std::cout << std::forward<Args>(args) << ' '), 0) ... };` (C++11)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
void print (T&& t) {
    std::cout << t << '\n';
}

template <class T, class... Args>
void print(T&& t, Args &&... args) {
  std::cout << t << ',';
  print(args...);
}

int main() {
  print(1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8);
  return 0;
}
```

Note that this calls `cout` once+ per element printed , when ideally, you'd construct a string and call `cout` once.

But that's on you :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the sample code using C++17

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T, class... Args>
void print(T&& t, Args &&... args)
{
    std::cout << t;
    ((std::cout << ", " << std::forward<Args>(args)), ...) ;
    std::cout << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    print(1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8);
    print(9);
    return 0;
}
```

Not that I feel it  is somehow superior to the accepted answer. Just to be complete...