# What should ellipsis in attribute-list in C++ be used for?

Tags: c++, attributes, ellipsis

In [C++ reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes) I found information about allowed syntax of attributes in C++, it is:

```
[[attribute-list]]
[[ using attribute-namespace : attribute-list ]]
```

"where attribute-list is a comma-separated sequence of zero or more attributes (possibly ending with an ellipsis ... indicating a pack expansion)"

I've tried to use its, but I see no difference between:

```
[[deprecated]] void f() 
{
}
```

and

```
[[deprecated...]] void f() 
{
}
```

In both cases output is the same.

Comment: *(possibly ending with an ellipsis ... indicating a pack expansion)* is what the reference says. When you could use it? No idea, it's an underdeveloped feature imho... Perhaps the grammar allows it for future expansions.

Comment: I believe [this paper](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n2843.html) may be relevant.

Comment: I wonder why does `[[deprecated...]]` even compile if there are no packs to expand.

Comment: You may find [this video](https://youtu.be/Pt6oeIpzue4) to be relevant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was added to the specification for consistency and also because the future of attributes is still being discussed. Considering that we currently have **pack expansion in variadic templates** (see [Variadic template pack expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25680461/variadic-template-pack-expansion)) like this:

```
// pack expansion in function arguments
template <typename... Args>
void f(Args... args) {}

// pack expansion in inheritance
template <typename... Inherited>
struct MyClass : Inherited... {};
```

Along the same lines, it also makes sense to think about pack expansion for attributes. A few example scenarios could be:

```
template <typename... Ts>
class [[Ts...]] MyClass {};
```

or

```
template <typename... Ts>
class [[Ts()...]] MyClass {};
```

But, again, this is only in the specification and currently there is no attribute that can be used like that.

Comment: Both examples of how they could be used fail to compile on GCC and clang even without instantiation. Is this expected?

Comment: But... how is a type an attribute? https://godbolt.org/z/TMz56hesb