# Recursive variadic void function using template params in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, recursion, variadic-templates

I'm willing to do something as simple as this:

```
template <typename I, typename... In>
void bar() {
    // Use I here
    bar<In...>(); // Enable recursion
}
```

However, this leads to "ambiguous call to overloaded function".
What makes me curious is that bellow code works:

```
template <typename T = void>
void foo() { }

template <int T, int... Tn>
void foo() {
    foo<Tn...>();
}
```

Why is that?
The following does works too:

```
void foobar() {}

template <typename I, typename... In>
void foobar(I i, In... in) {
    foobar(in...);
}
```

So, whats the simplest way to achieve recursion, given this function signature **WITHOUT USING ANY BRACED-INIT-LIST TECHNIQUES**:

```
template <typename I, typename... In>
void bar();
```

Comment: You need to end the recursion at some point, right? That's why you have to declare the empty parameter list case.

Comment: The first one doesn't work because eventually it tries to call `bar<>();`.

Comment: What do you mean by *"braced-init-list techniques"*? I see no braced init lists in your question.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat thanks for your reply. One could use a braced-init-list to solve my problem, that that wouldnt be a solution for me.

Comment: Now I'm curious. Can you show such solution?

Comment: I'm curious too and I don't understand what you mean with "braced-init-list techniques". Please, can you show an example?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/25683817/5446775

Comment: Since you mentioned that, why do you think that trick won't work in your case?

Comment: @max66 (Ping in case you didn't get notified.)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat because that's c++1z thing  (prototype c++17) and probably not supported (yet or fully), question is c++11

Comment: @Swift Nope, it's C++11. We are not talking about fold expressions.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat - thanks (and it was so obvious :( ).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I didn't say it wouldn't work, I said that's not the way I want to solve this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve in the same way `foo()` solve: when the `Tn...` list is empty, `foo<>()` is called, so the `foo()` version with a **type** template parameter (but with a default value) is called (the compiler match `foo<>()` with `foo<void>()`).

For `bar()` you can switch integer and types.

You can add a terminal version that receive a non-type template parameter with a default value

```
template <int = 0>
void bar()
 { }
```

so when you call `bar()` with a empty `In...` type list, the compiler match the call `bar<>()` with `bar<0>()`.

**--- EDIT ---**

The OP ask

> If `foo<>()` matches with `foo<void>()`, why doesnt `bar<>()` match with `bar<void>()` (`template <typename Dummy = void>` instead of `template <int = 0>)`? In other words, why does it have to be a `template <int = 0>` (of `int` type)?

First of all, why `foo()` works?

Because there are a `foo()` variadic template function that receive one or more integers and a `foo()` template that receive a single type (defaulted).

So, when you call `foo<>`, it doesn't match the integer variadic version (because at least one integer in required) and match the type version (activating the `void` default type).

Second: why `bar()` doesn't works adding a version that receive a single (and defaulted) type?

Because you have a variadic template function that receive one or more types

```
template <typename I, typename... In>
void bar ()
 { bar<In...>(); }
```

so if you add a version that receive one type (defaulted)

```
template <typename = void>
void bar ()
 { }
```

you get into trouble the compiler: wich version choose when you call `bar()` with the last type?

I mean: you call `bar<int, long>()` and only the variadic version match.

But the variadic version call `bar<long>()`.

The problem now is that both versions of `bar()` (the variadic one and the one with a single type) match.

So the compiler give you an error.

The trick is to create a `bar()` version with a single defaulted template parameter that can match the empty list call (`foo<>()`) but doesn't clash with the type variadic version.

A possible solution is the `int` one, but you can choose other types (`char`, `long`, `unsigned long long` and others) or even a version based on a template-template defaulted parameter.

I mean... instead of

```
template <int = 0>
void bar ()
 { }
```

you can use

```
template <template <typename...> class = std::vector>
void bar()
 { }
```

This isn't a suggestion: I think the `int = 0` is the simpler to write and understand. Just to show another possible way.

The point is adding a template that receive a single defaulted value but not a typename one.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat - I'm agree: I don't understand the "braced-init-list" part.

Comment: If `foo<>()` matches with `foo<void>()`, why doesnt `bar<>()` match with `bar<void>()` (`template <typename Dummy = void>` instead of `template <int = 0>`)? In other words, why does it have to be a `template <int = 0>` (of int type)? It looks like a ugly hack and confusing to understand

Comment: @YvesHenri - answer modified trying to explaining the point (I think it's a wonderful hack and I didn't know it; thanks)