# Variadic Template Function Call

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr, compile-time

Let's suppose we have the following *variadic template function*:

```
template <int... Ints> 
void foo() {
  Foo<Ints...> f;
  // do something with f.
}
```

Note that `foo` need a sequence of integers at *compile time*, in order to build `Foo` class.

We can simply invoke it:

```
foo<1, 2, ,3 , 4>();
```

Is there any method to "mitigate" this function call?
For example, to have something like:

```
foo(1, 2, 3, 4);
```

Notes:

- No C-style (*Macro*, or `vargs`).
- `foo` needs compile time sequence of integers.
- Any C++ standard is fine.

Comment: that's possible for _types_  but non-type parameter pack you have no way to deduce those. pretty much macro is only way here (va_args are run-time, not  compile time)

Comment: But... why? Also, a variadic macro could be a pretty clean solution if you _really_ have to have this notation. In GCC: `#define foo(...) _foo< __VA_ARGS__ >()`. However, really, I see no good point.

Comment: I don't understand why do you want "mitigate" the template value based function call; what's wrong with it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25680461/variadic-template-pack-expansion AND http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack  Should be `foo(Ints... args)`

Comment: `constexpr` arrays, initializer lists and ctors are a thing. This smells of abusing templates, there isn't really enough context to know if this is even the approach you should be taking.

Comment: How about `foo(1_c, 2_c, 3_c, 4_c)` with `operator""_c` which creates `std::integral_constant`

Comment: @Jarod42 - nice idea; IMHO, you should propose it as an answer.