# Variadic Dispatch Function

Tags: c++17, variadic-templates

I have an interface wherein the types of the parameters mostly encode their own meanings.  I have a function that takes one of these parameters.  I'm trying to make a function that takes a set of these parameters and performs the function on each one in order.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

enum param_type{typeA,typeB};

template <param_type PT> struct Container{
  int value;
  Container(int v):value(v){}
};

int f(Container<typeA> param){
  std::cout<<"Got typeA with value "<<param.value<<std::endl;
  return param.value;
}
int f(Container<typeB> param){
  std::cout<<"Got typeB with value "<<param.value<<std::endl;
  return param.value;
}
```

My current solution uses a recursive variadic template to delegate the work.

```cpp
void g(){}
template <typename T,typename...R>
void g(T param,R...rest){
  f(param);
  g(rest...);
}
```

I would like to use a packed parameter expansion, but I can't seem to get that to work without also using the return values. (In my particular case the functions are void.)

```cpp
template <typename...T> // TODO: Use concepts once they exist.
void h(T... params){
  // f(params);...
  // f(params)...;    // Fail to compile.
  // {f(params)...};
  std::vector<int> v={f(params)...}; // Works
}
```

Example usage

```cpp
int main(){
  auto a=Container<typeA>(5);
  auto b=Container<typeB>(10);
  g(a,b);
  h(a,b);
  return 0;
}
```

Is there an elegant syntax for this expansion in C++?

Comment: Please choose: c++11 , c++14 or c++17? And you may have a look here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58588748/folding-of-template-parameter-packs-in-pre-c17-idiomatic-approach#comment103491591_58588748)

Comment: Probably you're looking for a comma operator and fold expression `(f(params) , ... )`

Comment: @smitsyn fold expressions are introduced in c++17. Your solution may not working depending on the standard used in question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++17: use a fold expression with the comma operator.

```
template <typename... Args>
void g(Args... args)
{
    ((void)f(args), ...);
}
```

Before C++17: comma with `0` and then expand into the braced initializer list of an `int` array.  The extra `0` is there to ensure that a zero-sized array is not created.

```
template <typename... Args>
void g(Args... args)
{
    int arr[] {0, ((void)f(args), 0)...};
    (void)arr;                            // suppress unused variable warning
}
```

In both cases, the function call expression is cast to `void` to avoid accidentally invoking a user-defined `operator,`.