# How exactly is expansion of a parameter pack evaluated with std::forward?

Tags: c++, c++17, variadic-templates

I wanted to better understand *parameter pack expansions*, so I decided to research a bit and, what once seemed obvious to me, stopped being so obvious after trying to understand what exactly is going on. Let's examine a standard parameter pack expansion with `std::forward`:

```
template <typename... Ts>
void foo(Ts&& ... ts) {
    std::make_tuple(std::forward<Ts>(ts)...);
}
```

My understanding here is that for any parameter pack `Ts`, `std::forward<Ts>(ts)...` will result in a comma-separated list of forwarded arguments with their corresponding type, e.g., for `ts` equal `1, 1.0, '1'`, the function body will be expanded to:

```
std::make_tuple(std::forward<int&&>(1), std::forward<double&&>(1.0), std::forward<char&&>('1'));
```

And that makes sense to me. Parameter pack expansion, used with a function call, results in a comma-separated list of calls to that function with appropriate arguments.

What seems to be bothering me is why then would we sometimes need to introduce the comma operator (`operator,`), if we want to call a bunch of functions in a similar manner? Seeing [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54913886/7151494), we can read this code:

```
template<typename T>
static void bar(T t) {}

template<typename... Args>
static void foo2(Args... args) {
    (bar(args), ...); // <- notice: comma here
}

int main() {
    foo2(1, 2, 3, "3");
    return 0;    
}
```

followed by information that it will result in the following expansion:

```
(bar(1), bar(2), bar(3), bar("3"));
```

Fair, makes sense, but... *why*? Why doing this, instead:

```
template<typename... Args>
static void foo2(Args... args) {
    (bar(args)...); // <- notice: no comma here
}
```

doesn't work? According to my logic ("*Parameter pack expansion, used with a function call, results in a comma-separated list of calls to that function with appropriate arguments*"), it should expand into:

```
(bar(1), bar(2), bar(3), bar("3"));
```

Is it because of `bar()` returning `void`? Well, changing `bar()` to:

```
template<typename T>
static int bar(T t) { return 1; }
```

changes nothing. I would imagine that it would just expand to a comma-separated list of `1`s (possibly doing some side effects, if `bar()` was designed as such). Why does this behave differently? Where is my logic flawed?

Comment: `void()` isn't a function call, it's a cast.

Comment: @0x499602D2 I believe I didn't state that it's a function call. I used it to make `void(std::forward<Ts>(ts)...);` compile. Just stuck with it afterwards. When I mention function calls, I mean the `bar()` and `std::forward()` calls.

Comment: *"Parameter pack expansion, used with a function call..."* for `void(bar(args)...)` the expansion doesn't occur within the function call for `bar` it happens inside of `void()`, which is not a function. If there's more than one argument it will fail.

Comment: @0x499602D2 "*parameter pack expansion*" - `...` "*used with a function call*" - `bar(args)`. If you think that I should phrase that differently here, I will gladly take my chance to clarify the intiention and edit the question.

Comment: @0x499602D2 *"If there's more than one argument it will fail*" - that would mean that my assumtion is incorrect in the case of `void(std::forward<Ts>(ts)...);`. The expansion does not evaluate to a list of comma-separated, forwarded arguments?

Comment: There's another feature that you're using when doing `(bar(args), ...)`. I forget what it's called though.

Comment: `void(std::forward<Ts>(ts)...);` [does not in fact compile](https://godbolt.org/z/UZAnZw). The term you are looking for is [fold expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik oh snap, it seems that I must've either omitted the call when I tested the samples or I screwed up somewhere else. Will make an according edit, thank you.

Comment: @Fureeish: `(args + ...)` won't have comma at all in expansion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> My understanding here is that for any parameter pack `Ts`, `std::forward<Ts>(ts)...` will result in a comma-separated list of forwarded arguments with their corresponding type

Well, there's your problem: that's not how it works. Or at last, not quite.

Parameter pack expansions and their nature are determined by *where they are used*. Pack expansions, pre-C++17, can only be used within certain grammatical constructs, like a braced-init-list or a function call expression. Outside of such constructs (the previous list is not comprehensive), their use simply is not allowed. Post-C++17, fold expressions allow them to be used across specific operators.

The reason for this is in part grammatical. Consider this: `bar(1, (2, 3), 5)`. This calls the function with 3 arguments; the expression `(2, 3)` resolves down to a single argument. That is, there is a difference between the comma used in an expression and the comma used as a separator between values to be used in a function call. This difference is made at the *grammatical* level; if I want to invoke the comma operator in the middle of a sequence of function arguments, I have to put that whole thing in `()` so that the compiler will recognize the comma as a comma expression operator, not a comma separator.

Non-fold pack expansions effectively expand to use the *separation* comma, not the expression comma. As such, they can only be expanded in places where the separation kind of comma is valid.

The reason `(bar(args)...)` doesn't work is because a `()` expression cannot take the second kind of comma.

Comment: That's put beautifully, thank you very much. Do you have any good sources worth recommending (other than, well, the standard) where can I learn more in detail about those contexts and templates? I know it's off-topic for StackOverflow to ask for such recommendations in questions, but I believe a little comment could slip through. I had my eyes on Josuttis' `C++ Templates, The Complete Guide`, but didn't order the book yet.