# How can I send a variable number of pairs of variables to a function

Tags: c++, parameter-passing, variadic-functions

I'm trying to write something similar to this:

```cpp
void loadImage(SDL_Renderer *ren, {SDL_Texture *&texture, const char *imagePath} ... ){
    for(int i = 0; i < numOfPairs; i++){
        SDL_Surface *curImage = IMG_Load(pairs[i].second);
        pairs[i].first = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(ren, curImage);
        SDL_FreeSurface(curImage);
    }
}
```

Where I have a variable number of pairs and each pair contains a texture and its correspondent path. I've no idea, which way would be best to approach this problem. I've thought about using the `<cstdarg>` library's variadic functions but I read on another question that that's not a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

the way that immediately comes to mind is std::vector. You could pass a vector of std::pair or of std::tuple if you are using a c++11 or better compiler.

very simple to do

```
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>

....


std::vector<std::tuple<SDL_texture, const char *>> args;

args.push_back(std::make_tuple(texture1, path1));
args.push_back(std::make_tuple(texture2, path2));
```

then your func

```
    void load_Image(SDL_renedred *ren, const std::vector<std::tuple<SDL_texture, const char *>> &args)
    {
         std::tuple<SDL_textture, const char*> &arg1 = args[0];
  // or if you have modern c++
         auto &arg1 = args[0];  
    }
```

(not compiled, probably got typos in it.)

Answer (score 0):

First of all write a function that will process each pair (i.e. what you have inside your for loop):

```
using ImagePair = std::pair<SDL_Texture*&, const char*>;

void processImage(ImagePair imgPair)
{
    SDL_Surface *curImage = IMG_Load(imgPair.second);
    imgPair.first = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(ren, curImage);
    SDL_FreeSurface(curImage);
}
```

Then if you have C++11 or above, you can use a brace-initialization trick to call `processImage()` for each argument:

```
template <typename ... Ts>
void loadImage(Ts ... ts)
{
    using dummy = int[];
    (void)dummy {0, (processImage(ts)), 0)... };
}
```

What you're doing here is taking advantage of the fact that the compiler knows it has to do a pack expansion inside a brace-initialization list. That way you can avoid having to write recursive variadic template functions yourself.

Here you are building a dummy array of integers, which is equal in size to the number of variadic arguments you pass in. For each argument you call the function `processImage()`, but using the comma operator you set the value in the array to 0. So you expand the pack and call `processImage()` for each argument while creating a dummy array. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25680461/variadic-template-pack-expansion) might explain it more clearly.

If you have C++17 or above, you can simplify further and use a fold expression:

```
template<typename... Ts>
void loadImage(Ts... args)
{
    (processImage(args),...);
}
```

Comment: May I ask for an explanation of `... = { (processImage(ts), 0)... };` because I feel it went over my head.

Comment: @SandWoodJones I've added an explanation above. Hope it is useful.

Answer (score 0):

Although I hate it, you can use `std::initializer_list` like:

```
#include <initializer_list>
#include <tuple>

void loadImage(SDL_Renderer *ren, std::initializer_list<std::tuple<SDL_Texture*&,const char *&>> pair_list ){
    for(auto p:pairlist){//initializer_list cannot be indexed but only iterated
        SDL_Surface *curImage = IMG_Load(p.second);
        p.first = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(ren, curImage);
        SDL_FreeSurface(curImage);
    };  
};

//call site:
loadImage(ren,{tie(tex1,path1),tie(tex2,path2),tie(tex3,path3)});
```

It is recommended to store your pointers in `std::unique_ptr` instants with costume deleter. And I guess you'd better change your data structue design to avoid tying objects like that - e.g. using a `std::map`:

```
#include <initializer_list>
#include <memory>
#include <map>

struct MySDLDeleter{
    void operator(SDL_Texture* texPtr){SDL_FreeTexture(texPtr);};
    void operator(SDL_Renderer * renPtr){SDL_FreeRenderer(renPtr);};
    void operator(SDL_Surface * srfPtr){SDL_FreeSurface(srfPtr);};
};

auto loadImage(std::unique_ptr<SDL_Renderer,MySDLDeleter> ren, std::initializer_list<const char *> path_list ){
    std::map<const char *,std::unique_ptr<SDL_Texture,MySDLDeleter> texMap;
    for(auto p:path_list ){
        std::unique_ptr<SDL_Surface ,MySDLDeleter> curImage = IMG_Load(p.second);
        texMap.insert(p,SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(ren.get(), curImage.get()));
    }; 
    return texMap; 
};

//call site:
auto texMap=loadImage(create_the_renderer_ptr(),{path1,path2,path3});
```