# decltype((void)T{}) in template Partial Specialization not deduce?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, partial-specialization

```
template<typename T,typename U = void>
struct Test
{
    static const int value = 0;
};
template<typename T>
struct Test<T, decltype((void)T{})>
{
    static const int value = 2;
};

template<typename T>
struct Test<T*,  decltype((void)T{})>
{
    static const int value = 1;
};

int main(){       
   cout<<Test<int*>::value<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

code on gcc/clang both get error:ambiguous ,but decltype  change to void_t is ok.why?

Comment: Could this be related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4031228/why-is-operator-void-not-invoked-with-cast-syntax

Comment: @alterigel I don't think so.change to decltype(T{},void())  error again

Comment: What are you trying to do here?

Comment: @NicolBolas I think use decltype is deduced context,but compiler don't think so. I want to know why?

Answer (score 0):

To me this looks like a compiler bug: do you really need side effects from `T{}`? The whole construct of `decltype((void)T{})` should discard zero-initialized `T`, allowing unevaluated side-effects — so what's the point of such side effect, if there are any? 
 If you simplify it by just using `void`, or even omitting the whole second type, the problem goes away immediately ([live demo on wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/6RwOrg4csTZad72g)):

```
template<typename T, typename U = void>
struct Test
{
    static const int value = 0;
};
template<typename T>
struct Test<T, void>
{
    static const int value = 2;
};

template<typename T>
struct Test<T*, void>
{
    static const int value = 1;
};

int main(){       
    std::cout << Test<int*>::value << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Maybe there are some intricate details that I missed, but I tried many variants, including combinations of `std::declval`, `std::result_of`, alias templates, typedefs, none of which gave me anything meaningful. 
 But if we move the `decltype((void)T{})` part out:

```
template<typename T>
using wrap = decltype((void)T{});

template<typename T>
struct Test<T, wrap<T>>
{
    static const int value = 2;
};
template<typename T>
struct Test<T*, wrap<T>>
{
    static const int value = 1;
};
```

GCC yells: `ambiguous template instantiation for 'struct Test<int*, void>'`. Which for me is a sign of something going in the wrong direction.