# How does the standard C++ assert() work and how do I redefine it?

Tags: c++, gcc, assert

In `assert.h` we can see

```
# define assert(__e) ((__e) ? (void)0 : __assert_func (__FILE__, __LINE__, \
                               __ASSERT_FUNC, #__e))
```

Because the target is embedded, I need to actually display the error message upon assertion failure, so I need to invoke the LCD write function. I tried the following:

```
void handleCriticalError(int err_num, char *fname, int line_num, const char *foo); // Halts the program!
#define ASSERT(__e) ((__e) ? (void)0 : handleCriticalError (0, __FILE__, __LINE__, __func__))
```

However, when I use it, I get a strange error.

```
ASSERT(1<2);
>error: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Werror=write-strings]
```

How do I tie my function to a custom assert, or to the standard assert, so that the function is called upon failed assertion?

Note that I do not need a full-featured, standard-adhering `assert` as is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5252375/custom-c-assert-macro). I am going to use it only as single statements on a line, with a simple comparison of variables or constants.

Comment: How it works is different for every implementation. I would not recommend to try changing it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The file name is probably a string constant (`const char*`), but your function takes a `char*` parameter. This mismatch causes the error.

If you declare the function parameter as `const char *fname` instead, the error should go away.

Answer (score 2):

Redefine you function:

```
void handleCriticalError(int err_num, char const *fname, int line_num, const char *foo);
```

note `const *fname` parameter that should accept `__FILE__`