# Replace 'Define macro' with empty implementation

Tags: c++, optimization

I usually use the `#define` macro to add code that will be here while compiling as debug time and not while compiling as release. For instance:

```
#ifdef NDEBUG
# define LOG(msg) (void)msg
#else
# define LOG(msg) MyDebugLogger(msg)
#endif
```

Instead of that, I was thinking of using plain function and, just not providing the body for the release method:

```
void MyDebugLogger(std::string const& msg);
```

In MyDebugLogger.cpp:

```
void MyDebugLogger(std::string const& msg)
{
#ifdef NDEBUG
    std::clog << msg << "\n"; // Or whatever
#else
    (void)msg;
#endif
}
```

I'm expecting that the compilers will have the power to strip out the call and add **no** extra cost in Release. Am I correct? 
For some reason, could it be a bad practice?

EDIT: My question is: If I use macros as before, I know that in Release mode, the executable will be smaller and faster, as all the code has been removed.
If I use the function, will it be the same? As the compiler may understand that the function does nothing and is not necessary. (Or it will add an extra, even small, for calling an empty function)

Comment: Why even include `(void)msg;`?

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann: if you have all warnings enabled (recommended), you will get a "unused parameter" warning otherwise.

Comment: Well, then why not `void MyDebugLogger(std::string const&) { }`, that is, remove `msg`.

Comment: A function with an empty body won't be a proper equivalent for an empty macro. that string must be constructed at runtime, etc...

Comment: Some general remarks, not an answer: for the compiler to optimize away the empty function, it needs to see its definition, or LTO must be enabled. You can get around the `(void)msg;` with `[[maybe_unused]]`, see e.g. my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49320892/). Last, changing the signature to `template <class T> void MyDebugLogger(T const& msg)` allows logging of everything that's streamable, without converting to string first. That may or may not help you.

Comment: @VTT The string need not be constructed if the compiler can prove it's unused. https://godbolt.org/z/mYKlln

Comment: @BaummitAugen [Not really](https://godbolt.org/z/FX9PZF) I guess your case only works because compiler is able to analyze a case of small string optimization when no allocation is required.

Comment: @VTT Clang [still gets it right](https://godbolt.org/z/ViyjIe), but good point.

Comment: No, it's not guaranteed that a compiler will "strip out" a call of a function that does nothing. Depending on compiler settings a fair few compilers will, IF the definition is visible to the compiler. If the function is defined in a different compilation unit from where it is called, then most compilers will not eliminate the call (that would require the compiler to analyse code across compilation units, which is not required, and not all compilers do it).  Notionally, a smart linker may eliminate the call to an empty function, but I'm not aware of any that do.

Comment: @VTT: GCC with `-Wall -Wextra`, [here is an example](https://godbolt.org/z/6fYBH1). I was referring to the function, not the macro btw (the code mentioned in the comment has a semicolon).

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann: omitting the parameter wouldn't work in the `#ifndef DEBUG` version then, the way OP is using the function now.

Comment: @VTT: the macro doesn't have the semicolon. Also, Micha's second comment explicitly mentions the function, i.e. suggests that the function parameter should be removed then.

Comment: @VTT: read the first three comments, it's the conversation between me and Micha, I don't see what's unclear about it. The "Well, ..." part is the reply to my comment. The first comment has a semicolon.

Comment: The conventional way is your first option but with the `NDEBUG` expansion empty, which will remove the parameter completely without relying on compiler optimisations. (Constructing strings is not free, and leaving potentially sensitive or embarrassing strings in the binary is a no-no.)

Answer (score 1):

practically you would do the same as with the macro:

```
void MyDebugLogger(std::string const& msg)
{
#ifdef NDEBUG
    std::clog << msg << "\n"; // Or whatever
#endif
}
```

Comment: Well... Yes! :) I'll edit my post as my question is (even with your solution) do this call add an extra-cost at release. We (human) know that it can be completely removed.

Comment: :) seeing it this way is a bit different. To be honest, I dont know what the compiler does with an empty function body. Maybe it depends on the implementation of the compiler. If you embedd all calls to MyDebugLogger in the #ifdef statement, it sure would be left out completely. But then you would have more coding overhead

Answer (score 1):

You'r example should work, with a little tweak. In your current version the compiler "sees" just the function signature and will emit a call to it's symbol, which will later be resolved via the linker, so it can't optimize it out on it's own. (Link Time Optimizations might help with that, but that depends very much on you'r setup and dynamic linking would make this impossible). So maybe try something like this
in the header:

```
// Assuming you are using clang or gcc,
// but is required to not give an error by the standard and probably
// not even needed.
[[gnu::always_inline]] 
void MyDebugLogger(std::string const& msg [[maybe_unused]])
{
  #ifdef NDEBUG
    MyDebugLoggerImplementation(msg);
  #endif
}
```

And then implement it in you .cpp file. Another benefit of this method is that you
method needs the Logger to be compiled with NDEBUG while this method gives the client code the choice.