# Should a diagnostic be emmited for discarded value expressions that do not have side effects?

Tags: c++, debugging, warnings, comma-operator

After quite some debugging time I felt silly to discover a goof in my code that boils down to something like this :

```
int main()
{
    double p1[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
    double p2[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
    int color = 1;
    bool some_condition = true;

    if (some_condition) (p1, p2, color);
}
```

The `(p1, p2, color)` expression evaluates to its last operant, but should the compiler protect me in some way ? (Visual Studio told nothing)

And yes you guessed it right, I wanted to call a draw function : `Draw(p1, p2, color)`

Comment: I would expect a warning for being unused.

Comment: @chris Which is what I get from clang. And from g++ with `-Wall`.

Comment: @JosephMansfield, Indeed. It's even three warnings, so it really catches your eye.

Comment: @chris I was using color in a later place in code .... I guess then it was all on me

Comment: However, Visual Studio does not complain, even with /Wall

Comment: @NikosAthanasiou It's a warning about the expression result being unused, not the variable.

Comment: Added some more details to my answer that may help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does the comma operator \`,\` do in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/52550/what-does-the-comma-operator-do-in-c)

Comment: @MohitJain All expressions have a type

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++ the expression `(p1, p2, color)` forces the compiler to interpret the commas inside the parentheses as the *sequential-evaluation operator*. 
The sequential-evaluation operator is a binary operator that evaluates its first operand as `void` and discards the result, it then evaluates the second operand and returns its value and type. Therefore, the expression `(p1, p2, color)` is going to be evaluated in the following way:

1. First `p1` is evaluated and discarded, then `(p2, color)` is evaluated and the result `(p2, color)` is returned.
2. First `p2` is evaluated and discarded, then `color` is evaluated and the result `color` is returned.

Thus the statement:

```
if (some_condition) (p1, p2, color);
```

Is equivalent to:

```
if (some_condition) color;
```

Some compilers might raise a warning because during the evaluation of the expression `(p1, p2, color)` the evaluations of `p1` and `p2` will result in unused:

[<kbd>**CLANG LIVE DEMO**</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/98624c58d6bb5251)
[<kbd>**GCC LIVE DEMO**</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/70b6b0772c8aeb30)
(As you already mentioned *Visual Studio* will raise no warning at all.)

Apart from these warnings the code is legitimate C++ (i.e., C++ syntax isn't violated).

Now, whether the compiler should protect you is debatable. In my humble opinion it should protect you, since such expressions although correct from C++ syntax point of view might result, in very hard to spot bugs (e.g., the case of assingment inside an `if` expression).

Comment: "The compiler will raise a warning" - you mean, "some compilers will raise a warning, if you enable suitable warnings". There's no requirement to diagnose this, and apparently the OPs compiler doesn't (at least with default settings).

Answer (score 3):

It is perfectly valid code, so the compiler does not have to issue a diagnostic although having a diagnostic would be helpful in this case. This is one of the reasons many developers prefer `clang` since they tend to go [above what is required when it comes to diagnostic](http://clang.llvm.org/diagnostics.html).

For the standards rules on diagnostic messages, we can go to the [draft C++ standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf) section `1.4` *Implementation compliance* which says (*emphasis mine*):

> 1. The set of **diagnosable rules consists of all syntactic and semantic
>      rules** in this International Standard except for those rules containing
>      an explicit notation that “no diagnostic is required” or which are
>      described as resulting in “undefined behavior.”
> 2. Although this International Standard states only requirements on C++
>      implementations, those requirements are often easier to understand if
>      they are phrased as requirements on programs, parts of programs, or
>      execution of programs. Such requirements have the following meaning:
>
>    - If a program **contains no violations of the rules** in this International Standard, a conforming implementation
>        shall, within its resource limits, **accept and correctly execute**<sup>2</sup> that program.
>    - If a program **contains a violation of any diagnosable rule** or an occurrence of a construct described in
>        this Standard as “conditionally-supported” when the implementation does not support that construct,
>        a conforming implementation shall issue **at least one diagnostic message.**
>    - If a program contains a violation of a rule for which no diagnostic is required, this International Standard places no requirement on implementations with respect to that program.

No syntactic or semantic rules are violated by this program and so no diagnostic is required.

We have the following code:

```
if (some_condition) (p1, p2, color);
                    ^  ^   ^
                    1  2   3
```

`1` is an *expression-statement* which is valid in this context for and *if statement*. We can see this by going to the grammar:

```
if ( condition ) statement
```

and:

```
statement:
  attribute-specifier-seqopt expression-statement
```

and:

```
expression-statement:
  expressionopt;
```

and:

```
primary-expression:
  ( expression )
```

Both `2` and `3` are the *comma operator* which will evaluate the left operand and discard the value and then evaluate the right operand again nothing invalid here.

So what does section `5.18` *Comma operator* says:

> A pair of expressions separated by a comma is evaluated left-to-right;
>   the left expression is a discarded value expression (Clause 5).<sup>83</sup>

and a *discarded value expression* is covered in section `5` which says:

> In some contexts, an expression only appears for its side effects.
>   Such an expression is called a discarded-value expression.

So since the value of the result of the left hand expression is discarded then we must only care about the *side-effect*. In your specific case evaluating the variable has no other effect besides generating a value hence the warning, but if you had used a function in their place e.g.:

```
bool func()
{
    //...
}
```

and change your code to:

```
if (some_condition) (func(), func(), func() );
```

neither `clang` nor `gcc` will provide a warning since presumably `func` will perform some *side-effet* that you care about.

Comment: But you would accept that a compiler might well go above and beyond and issue a warning at some level?

Comment: @david.pfx of course, I added a minor clarification in my answer.

Comment: Can you clarify: S5/11 `an expression only appears for its side-effects ... is called a discarded-value expression.` If there are no side-effects, then what?

Comment: @david.pfx added more details.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24912609/what-is-the-use-of-a-statement-with-no-effect-in-c/24914158#24914158. MSVC apparently warns if you cast to void.

Comment: @david.pfx which seems like the opposite of what you want to do.

Comment: my ideal would be that all compilers warn about all statements that have no effect (including discarded value if no side effects); that all compilers accept a missing argument name as an intentional unused argument; and that no-one ever writes or needs to write a cast to void. World peace would be nice too.