# Impossible C++ array indexing

Tags: c++, arrays, indexing, g++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In C arrays why is this true? a[5] == 5[a]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/381542/in-c-arrays-why-is-this-true-a5-5a)
>   [Accessing arrays by index[array] in C and C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5073350/accessing-arrays-by-indexarray-in-c-and-c)

I just found what seems to be a bug in my code, but not only it compiles, it also works as expected initially...

Consider the following code snipet:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class WeirdTest
{
public:
    int value;
    string text;
    WeirdTest() : value(0),
                  text("")
    {}
    virtual ~WeirdTest()
    {}
    void doWeirdTest()
    {
        value = 5;
        string name[] =
        {
            "Zero",
            "One",
            "Two",
            "Three",
            "Four",
            "Five"
        };
        text = value[name];
        cout << "text: " << text << endl;
    }
};
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    WeirdTest test;
    test.doWeirdTest();
    return 0;
}
```

Instead of having `text=value[name];` it should have been `text=name[value];` but the compiler does not complain, and the resulting binary code is the exact same whether the "bug" is here or not. 
I'm compiling using g++ 4.6.3, and if someone know what is going on here I would be very grateful. Could it be something in the standard that I missed ? Automatic bug-fix in C++0x maybe ? ;)

Thanks a lot,

Cheers !

Comment: It's behavior that's inherited from C.  See: http://www.c-faq.com/aryptr/joke.html

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8969684/accessing-array-contents-xn-vs-nx/8969755#8969755 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5073350/accessing-arrays-by-indexarray-in-c-and-c

Answer (score 9):

Yes, that's a curious "feature". Actually what happens is that the compiler translates the `a[i]` into `*(a + i)`, so array index and array address are actually interchangeable.

Note, it's valid only if `operator []` isn't overloaded.

Comment: Thanks a lot for these answers guys ! I've learned something today :)

Comment: This "feature" was a standard trick used by entries in the Obfuscated C Contest.