# String tricky printf statement

Tags: c, arrays, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Accessing arrays by index[array] in C and C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5073350/accessing-arrays-by-indexarray-in-c-and-c)

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{       
    int a=3, b = 5;
    printf(&a["Ya!Hello! how is this? %s\n"], &b["junk/super"]);
    printf(&a["WHAT%c%c%c  %c%c  %c !\n"], 1["this"],
    2["beauty"],0["tool"],0["is"],3["sensitive"],4["CCCCCC"]);

    return 0;
}
```

This is one of the practice problems that I was given in class. I'm trying to figure out how this code was able to get to the output, which is

Hello! how is this? super 
That is C !

The &a[" %s"] operation. How does that work? along with the seco

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75538/hidden-features-of-c#76801

Comment: `x[y]` is the same as `y[x]` is the same as `*(x+y)`. So `&a[b]` is the same as `(a + b)`. `("foobar"+3)` is the same as `"bar"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code

```
&a["Ya!Hello! how is this? %s\n"]
```

Is interpreted as

```
&(a["Ya!Hello! how is this? %s\n"])
```

Since all C-style strings are pointers, this is a bizarre but legal usage of the fact that

```
arr[i]
```

and

```
i[arr]
```

are both legal in C.  Consequently, the code should be interpreted as

```
&("Ya!Hello! how is this? %s\n"[a])
```

And since `a = 3`, this is the character `H`.  Since we take the address of this character, this gives a pointer to the C-style string

```
"Hello! how is this? %s\n"
```

Using this as a starting point, you can try to decode the rest of the program.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you! That helps. But could you just explain the arr[i] and i[arr] relation. Are you saying that arr[5] can be also 5[arr]? They are equivalent?

Comment: @Nopiforyou- Yep!  `arr[i] = *(arr + i) = *(i + arr) = i[arr]`.

Comment: Wow thank you. I can't help but wonder if this is common or rather an obscure part of C. I've definitely never seen it written this way before.

Comment: @Nopiforyou- This is ridiculously obscure.  I teach a CS course and would never put something like this in it... you will almost never see code like this.

Comment: @Nopiforyou: This is rare in real-life code, yet very well-known as a curiosity. Basically, this is a heavily overused C anecdote.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you have to understand that string literal is an array of `char` elements. Which means that you can use string literal in the same way you would use any other array. This is a legal C expression

```
"hello"[i]
```

which will evaluate to the `i`th character of the string "hello". For example, `"hello"[1]` gives you access to character that stores `e`.

Secondly, you have to understand that in a legal `a[i]` expression `a` and `i` can be swapped without changing the meaning of the expression. This means that

```
i["hello"]
```

is also legal and also gives you access to the `i`th character of string "hello". So, if `i` is equal to 2, then `i["hello"]` refers to the first `l`.

Now, this is already sufficient to decipher the original code, assuming you know what `printf` is and how it works.