# Indexing array incorrectly in c++

Tags: c++

Today when i was coding inside my visual studio i unintentionally did following

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    cout<<"Value is"<<[i]arr<<endl;
}
```

instead of arr[i] and it worked.why it worked?

Comment: Because that's a totally valid syntax for indexing an array.

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5073350/accessing-arrays-by-indexarray-in-c-and-c

Comment: It's not *incorrect*, it's just semantically unclear.  Well, silly, anyway.  It's the kind of thing that interviewers and professors like to discuss, and will get you shot in a code review.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because `[i]arr == *(i + arr) == arr[i]`

Note: `+` operator holds `commutative` property

Comment: oh i see that is very awesome