# not able to understand how compiler(gcc) is interpreting the command(c) and giving output of the statement

Tags: c, arrays

Can anyone help me out, I am not getting how gcc is compiling the below statement and printing its output.:-

```
printf("%d",7["sunderban"]);
```

Comment: Gcc is taking base address of "sunderban" adding 7 to it and printing the decimal equivalent of data at that location,which is for 'a' is 97.

Comment: You are asking about the output of that statement, without stating what this output is, and why it's unexpected to you. Please improve your question.

Answer (score 0):

C allows to access array's elements in two ways (see [Accessing arrays by index[array] in C and C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5073350/accessing-arrays-by-indexarray-in-c-and-c) and the answers) :

```
int v[5];
// 1)
v[2] = 33;
// 2)
2[v] = 44;
```

So, what happens in your case is that you access the 8th element of the string, and it is interpret as int by the printf.