# cout << 2["abc"] << endl; why is it working? which syntax is it?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(void) {
    cout << 2["abc"] << endl;
    return 0;
}

$ g++ test.cpp -o test
$ ./test
c
```

What the C++ syntax is? Why it work? Can someone explain it?

Comment: Just because it works, doesn't mean you should use it.

Comment: Just because you shouldn't use it, doesn't mean you shouldn't ask why it works.

Comment: just because I ask why it works, I figured it out   Thanks everyone!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because `a[b]` is `*(a + b)`<sup>1</sup> and `b[a]` is `*(b + a)`, and `+` is commutative.

<sub><sup>1</sup> unless overloaded and other shenanigans.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

Array indexing is cummutative. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5073350/accessing-arrays-by-indexarray-in-c-and-c) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/381542/with-c-arrays-why-is-it-the-case-that-a5-5a).

In your case, *narrow string literals* are basically *const array of characters*. Which makes:

```
cout << 2["abc"] << endl;
```

same as

```
cout << "abc"[2] << endl;
```

---

To partially quote (emphasis mine):

[[lex.string/8]](http://eel.is/c++draft/lex.string#8)

> ...A narrow string literal has type ***“array of n const char”***...

[[expr.sub/1]](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.post#expr.sub-1)

> A postfix expression followed by an expression in square brackets is a
>   postfix expression. **One of the expressions** shall be a glvalue of type
>   ***“array of T”*** or a prvalue of type “pointer to T” and the other shall be a prvalue of unscoped enumeration or ***integral type***. The result is
>   of type “T”....

---

Note: it only works for arrays. When you do:

```
struct Foo
{
    Foo& operator[](std::size_t index) { return *this; }
};

Foo foo;
```

Below will work work because its actually calling `foo.operator[] (2)`;

```
Foo f;
f[2];    //Calls foo.operator[] (2);
```

Below will not work because, one of the expressions is not *an array*, hence the compiler proceeds to find a suitable `2.operator[] (foo)`, which would fail because *integral types* have no member functions.

```
2[f];   //will not work
```