# How does this array element access syntax work?

Tags: arrays, c, printf

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a[] = {1, 2, 3};

    printf("%d", 0[a]);
    printf("\n%d", 2[a]);

    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
1
3
```

I know how to access the array element with the index, but how this above syntax accessing the first value in both scenarios and add the prefixed numbers?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5073350/accessing-arrays-by-indexarray-in-c-and-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C, the arrays and pointers have similarities. When you access an array element `array[3]`. This is equivalent to:

```
*(array + 3) // Dereferencing the 3rd index from beginning
```

Similarly, when you try to access it like `3[array]`, the statement goes like:

```
*(3 + array) // Identical to the first example
```

Which is identical. Lastly, when you want to obtain the N-th element of an array `N[array]`, the syntax becomes:

```
*(N + array)
```

That's why you get your expected output.