# Why an array pointer with index returns the value in that index instead of returning the specific index adress?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

i was practicing pointers and i saw that when i define a pointer and assign an array to that pointer, i was able to get the  value in a specific index when i use the pointer name with that index instead of array name, like,

```
  int arr[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
  int *ptr;

  ptr = arr;
  
  printf("%d", ptr[1]); // prints out 2
```

I was expecting to see the value when i use *ptr[1] and the specific index adress when i use ptr[1], but when i use *ptr[1] i get compiler error. I thought pointer name keeps the adress and using the name with * gives the value in that adress.

Am i missing something here ? Why pointer with array works that way ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing arrays by index\[array\] in C and C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5073350/accessing-arrays-by-indexarray-in-c-and-c)

Comment: `[]` actually always expect a pointer. It does the de-referencing for you, so it's the same as `*ptr` but indexed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The misunderstanding here is that pointers and arrays have similar behaviours in C, as in you can treat a pointer like an array, and an array like a pointer.

In effect `x[n]` is the same as `*(x + n)` and vice-versa. `x[0]` is just `*x`.

As such, `ptr[1]` will return a de-referenced `int*` or in other words an `int`.

If you want the actual address you need to do either `ptr + n` or `&ptr[n]`, both of which are equivalent, they're `int*`.

Comment: I think i got it, arrays are just pointers points to multiple adresses and [] operator adds the size of the data type times index with arrays initial adress. am i right ?

Comment: C is not an especially sophisticated language, it's called "fancy assembly" for a reason. A pointer is just an "indirect" way of referring to something, and you can "dereference" it to get that value. Both `x[0]` and `*x` pick out the value the pointer is pointing at. `x[n]` and `*(x + n)` pick out a value `n` places ahead from that pointer.

Comment: If you look at the assembly output of compiled C code you can see how it's quite literally pointer manipulation and "fetch from address" type operations.

Comment: 'you can treat a pointer like an array, and an array like a pointer'......sometimes.

Comment: @MartinJames Let's not get too pedantic here.

Comment: @tadman computer systems are really, really pedantic.

Comment: @MartinJames When I explain like this it's to paint the general picture. C has so many caveats it goes without saying that general rules do not always apply. Please don't confuse the issue.