# Basic Calculator: How to script a function for deleting digits one by one? (GDScript)

Tags: button, godot, gdscript

How am I supposed to code a button that deletes digits in a basic calculator one by one?

Heres my script so far: https://pastebin.com/xLj2iCHU

```
func _on_BDeleteDigit_pressed():
    var numberAdded
    var numberBefore = $NumberStuffs.get_text()
    numberAdded = numberAdded.length() - 1
    numberAdded[numberBefore]=("")
    $Outputlabel.set_text(str(numberAdded))
```

This is also the error when the delete button is pressed:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8OJTI.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explaining the error

I'll start with the error. It says

> Nonexistent function 'length' in base 'Nil'

The error is telling you that you are trying call a function called `length` on something that is `Nil`, but `Nil` does not have a function called `length`.

The problem is that you are trying to call something on `Nil`. What are you trying to call? `length`. So where is that? That is here:

```
numberAdded = numberAdded.length() - 1
```

So, `numberAdded` is `Nil`. The next question is why. So, let us see where `numberAdded` got its value…

So you declare it here:

```
var numberAdded
```

Then we have this line that has nothing to do with it:

```
var numberBefore = $NumberStuffs.get_text()
```

And then the line with the error:

```
numberAdded = numberAdded.length() - 1
```

What did you expect `numberAdded.length()` to be, if `numberAdded` does not have a value? Of course that is an error.

---

By the way, the code suggests that you expected `numberAdded` to be, well, a number. Which makes me wonder what you expected from this:

```
numberAdded[numberBefore]=("")
```

Yes you can do [the inverted indexing thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5073350/accessing-arrays-by-indexarray-in-c-and-c) in C or C++, because it is just adding pointers. But not GDScript, you don't.

---

I suspect that using types would help you. For example declare `numberAdded` to be an integer like this: `var numberAdded:int`. *Yes, [GDScript has types](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/getting_started/scripting/gdscript/static_typing.html), use them.*

---

### How to delete the last character

Let me take as reference how you add a digit:

```
func _on_Button1_pressed():
    var currentNumber = $NumberStuffs.get_text()
    
    currentNumber = currentNumber + "1"
    $NumberStuffs.set_text(currentNumber)
```

Alright, we are storing a string on the `text` property of the node `$NumberStuffs`. And we add a digit by concatenating to it.

The above code should be is equivalent to this:

```
func _on_Button1_pressed():
    $NumberStuffs.text += "1"
```

*If `get_text` and `set_text` are custom functions in GDScript, you may want to look into [`setget`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/getting_started/scripting/gdscript/gdscript_basics.html).*

---

Thus, the question is **how to remove the last character of a string**. There are several ways!

One way would be using [`erase`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_string.html#class-string-method-erase):

```
func _on_BDeleteDigit_pressed():
    var text := $NumberStuffs.text
    var length := text.length()
    text.erase(length - 1, 1)
    $NumberStuffs.text = text
```

*Note that `erase` is modifying the string, but the string is a copy we got from reading `$NumberStuffs.text` (or calling `$NumberStuffs.get_text`), which is why we need to set to `$NumberStuffs.text` (or call `$NumberStuffs.set_text`) anyway.*

Or if you prefer:

```
func _on_BDeleteDigit_pressed():
    var text := $NumberStuffs.get_text()
    var length := text.length()
    text.erase(length - 1, 1)
    $NumberStuffs.set_text(text)
```

---

Alternatively, we might get a string which is like the one we have except lacking the last character. We can do that with [`left`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_string.html#class-string-method-left) (which lets you get a portion of the string from the left, there is also a [`right`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_string.html#class-string-method-right) function that does the same but from the right):

```
func _on_BDeleteDigit_pressed():
    var length := $NumberStuffs.text.length()
    $NumberStuffs.text = $NumberStuffs.text.left(length - 1)
```

Or, if you prefer:

```
func _on_BDeleteDigit_pressed():
    var text := $NumberStuffs.get_text()
    var length := text.length()
    $NumberStuffs.set_text(text.left(length - 1))
```

---

In general we can get a string containing a portion of another string with [`substr`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_string.html#class-string-method-substr):

```
func _on_BDeleteDigit_pressed():
    var length := $NumberStuffs.text.length()
    $NumberStuffs.text = $NumberStuffs.text.substr(0, length - 1)
```

Or, if you prefer:

```
func _on_BDeleteDigit_pressed():
    var text := $NumberStuffs.get_text()
    var length := text.length()
    $NumberStuffs.set_text(text.substr(0, length - 1))
```

---

And yes, you can modify the string by indexing it, which I believe is what you were trying. For example:

```
$NumberStuffs.text[-1] = "a"
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
var length := $NumberStuffs.text.length()
$NumberStuffs.text[length - 1] = "a"
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
var text := $NumberStuffs.get_text()
var length := text.length()
text[length - 1] = "a"
$NumberStuffs.set_text(text)
```

Will replace the last character with an "a". And yes, you could remove by doing that. That would be:

```
$NumberStuffs.text[-1] = ""
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
var length := $NumberStuffs.text.length()
$NumberStuffs.text[length - 1] = ""
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
var text := $NumberStuffs.get_text()
var length := text.length()
text[length - 1] = ""
$NumberStuffs.set_text(text)
```

---

By the way, I have been using `:=` when declaring the variables. That declares the variable of the type of whatever I'm using to initialize them.

Comment: This is a great explanation for what I need! Kudos to you :)