# Why does inserting URLs in C and C++ code work?

Tags: c++, c, url

Why does the following code compile? Which section of the language allows URLs to be added in C and C++ code?

```
int main()
{
     http://www.stackoverflow.com
     return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance, Castro.

Comment: I went ahead and properly formatted your question using the code formatting, instead of block quote - that makes it pretty obvious, as Daniel said.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75538/hidden-features-of-c/78840#78840

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you compiled with warnings, you would notice:

```
warning: label ‘http’ defined but not used
```

That should be indicative enough of the problem here.

The `http:` text is treated as a label.

Followed by `//` negating the remaining text as a comment, ignoring it.

```
http://www.stackoverflow.com
```

Even the SO syntax colour schemes indicated as above show this to be true, as the section after the http, is treated as a comment (grayed out).

Answer (score 3):

It's because the compiler treats `http:` as a label and `// whatever` as a comment. This is perfectly legal code.

Unless you use `goto http;` somewhere however, it'll be completely useless code.

Answer (score 1):

In your code `http` is just a label and `//www.stackoverflow.com` is a comment.

Also note that

```
int main()
{
     http://www.stackoverflow.com
}
```

or

```
int main()
{
 http://www.stackoverflow.com
 http://www.facebook.com
 return 0;
}
```

won't compile.