# Boost.Variant, Boost.MPL: How to append types?

Tags: c++, boost, types, boost-mpl, boost-variant

I look at this [grate code based on boost.Any](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8304873/1056328) and cant help but wonder if we could  use [Boost.Variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/variant.html) instead. I wonder if such API would be possible:

```
void voidFunc()
{
    std::cout << "void called" << std::endl;
}

int stringFunc(std::string str)
{
    std::cout << str << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    some_map_like_type<std::string, boost::variant> funcs;
    funcs.insert<void , void >("voidFunc", &voidFunc)); // now our variant vould contain something like boost::function<void, void>
    funcs.insert<int , std::string>("stringFunc", &stringFunc)); // and now we added to our variant a new type: boost::function<int , std::string>
    funcs.insert<void , void >("voidFunc2", &voidFunc)); // and now our variant should not change because it already contains boost::function<void, void> type


    // And here when all the fun part is:
    funcs["voidFunc"](); // compiles
    funcs["stringFunc"]("hello"); // compiles
    funcs["stringFunc"](some_not_std_string_class); // does not compile.
    return 0;
}
```

That means that at the end compiler would have to compile something like:

```
void voidFunc()
{
    std::cout << "void called" << std::endl;
}

int stringFunc(std::string str)
{
    std::cout << str << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    some_map_like_type<std::string, boost::variant< boost::function<void , void>, boost::function<int , std::string> > > funcs;
    funcs.insert<void , void >("voidFunc", &voidFunc)); // now our variant vould contain something like boost::function<void, void>
    funcs.insert<int , std::string>("stringFunc", &stringFunc)); // and now we added to our variant a new type: boost::function<int , std::string>
    funcs.insert<void , void >("voidFunc2", &voidFunc)); // and now our variant should not change because it already contains boost::function<void, void> type


    // And here when all the fun part is:
    funcs["voidFunc"](); // compiles
    funcs["stringFunc"]("hello"); // compiles
    funcs["stringFunc"](some_not_std_string_class); // here it would give error and would not compile
    return 0;
}
```

### Update:

What have I tried (based on this [Variant docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/variant/tutorial.html) and this [MPL demos](http://www.crystalclearsoftware.com/cgi-bin/boost_wiki/wiki.pl?CPPTM_Answers_-_Chapter_3) and [docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/vector.html)):

```
#include <boost/static_assert.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/equal.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/vector_c.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/transform.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/multiplies.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/placeholders.hpp>

#include <boost/variant.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class sudo_science
{
public:
    typedef  boost::mpl::vector_c<int> types_vector1;

    typedef boost::make_recursive_variant< types_vector1 >::type recursive_variant_t;

    std::vector< recursive_variant_t > variant_seq;

    template <typename T>
    void append(T val)
    {
        typedef  boost::mpl::push_back<types_vector1,T>::type types_vector1;
        variant_seq.push_back(val);
        return;
    }

    std::vector< recursive_variant_t > give_me_end_variant()
     {
         return variant_seq;
     }
};

int main()
{
    sudo_science a;
    a.append<float>(1.0);
    a.append<std::string>("Stack and Boost");

    //sorry for C++11
    auto varint = a.give_me_end_variant();

    return 0;
}
```

But it fails to compile with 2 same errors:

```
Error   1   error C2665: 'boost::detail::variant::make_initializer_node::apply<BaseIndexPair,Iterator>::initializer_node::initialize' : none of the 2 overloads could convert all the argument types    c:\program files\boost\include\boost\variant\variant.hpp    1330    1
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? There's probably a much easier way.

Comment: The only diffculty is functions that differ in return type only. With overloading I can trivially resolve `funcs["stringFunc"]("hello");` and even figure out that `funcs["stringFunc"](some_not_std_string_class);` should not compile. But add a `function<int, std::string>` to the variant, and it falls apart.

Comment: @MSalters: described issue (tall me if its same you ran into?) [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8317375/boostvariant-and-function-types-in-it-how-to-resolve-error-c2066-cast-to-fun)

Comment: @GMan: Described problem/ what I try to accomplish [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8317375/boostvariant-and-function-types-in-it-how-to-resolve-error-c2066-cast-to-fun)

Answer (score -1):

It is not possible. `operator[]` is a run-time thing, while types are a compile-time thing. So should the compiler compile the following?

```
char const* str;
if (some_condition())
  str = "voidFunc";
else
  str = "stringFunc";
// ... some more code
if (some_condition())
  funcs[str]();
else
  funcs[str](str);
```

How is the compiler supposed to know whether the second call to `some_condition()` gives the same result as before? Or whether the code in between modified the value of `str`?

What about the following:

```
void call(some_map_like_type<std::string, boost::variant> const& funcs)
{
  funcs["voidFunc"]();
}
```

How is the compiler supposed to know whether at call time `funcs` contains an entry mapping `"voidFunc"`to a function with no arguments? And what should happen if it is called once on with a value that does, and once with a value which doesn't?

Depending on what you *actually* want to achieve, there might be a way to get it with templates and `constexpr` functions. However note that nothing which happens at runtime can affect whether the code compiles, for the simple reason that the code cannot be run before it is compiled.

Comment: updated q... I hope this can be done with something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8306743/c-can-we-collect-types)

Comment: Wrong answer, it's possible: the argument types are known.

Comment: @MSalters: No, the argument types to be accepted at compile time are *not* known. They are specified by calls to `funcs.insert<>`, and depend on which calls to this function have been done.

Comment: boost::variant has a finite number of contained types; `funcs.insert<>` cannot influence that set. You will get a compile-time error when you try to assign a variable of the wrong type to  that variant.

Comment: @MSalters: But if you read the question, that's exactly what myWallJSON asks for. And to that I answered.