# C++: can we collect types?

Tags: c++, boost, types

I wonder if we could do something like

```
a.pushType<int>
a.pushType<std::string>
a.pushType<char>
```

so than we could call

```
std::map<a.T1, a.T3> mymap;
std::map<a.T1, a.T2> mymap;
someClass<a.T1, a.T2, a.T3>
```

And I need it **not at run time** but at compile time (for providing it in my header only library.)

Is it possible with C++03 and Boost?

Comment: why can't you write `std::map<T1,T2` with `T1` &  `T2` appropriate types. Types are a compiler thing. Values exist at runtime.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's a mechanism called TypeLists; as far as I know it was first proposed by Andrei Alexandrescu in *Modern C++ Design*. There's an implementation of TypeLists in Alexandrescu's library, [Loki](http://loki-lib.sourceforge.net/). I also think Boost.MPL has a similar construct: the [vector](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/vector.html).

Comment: @myWallJSON: You edited the question. It was not clear before.

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef std::pair<int, std::string> a;

std::map<a::first_type, a::second_type> mymap;
```

The types must be known at compile time though.  There's ways around it but they are immensely complicated.