# C++ `operator function_type()` is such thing possible?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, operator-overloading

I try to compile [this answer related to how to store functional objects with difrent signature in a container (eg: std::map)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8304694/1056328)  I compeated (seems to me) provided answer code:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

class api {
    //maps containing the different function pointers
    std::map<std::string, void(*)()> voida;
    std::map<std::string, int(*)(std::string, const int&)> stringcrint;
    friend class apitemp;
public:
    //api temp class 
    //given an api and a name, it converts to a function pointer  
    //depending on parameters used
    class apitemp {
        const std::string* n;
        api* p;
    public:
        apitemp(const std::string* name, const api* parent) 
            : n(name), p(parent) {}
        operator void(*)()() 
        {return p->void[*n];}
        operator int(*)(std::string, const int&)() 
        {return p->stringcrint[*n];}
    }; 
    //insertion of new functions into appropriate maps
    void insert(std::string name, void(*ptr)()) 
    {voida[name]=ptr;}
    void insert(std::string name, int(*ptr)(std::string, const int&))
    {stringcrint[name]=ptr;}
    //operator[] for the name gets halfway to the right function
    apitemp operator[](std::string n) const {return apitemp(n, this);}
} myMap;

int hello_world(std::string name, const int & number )
{
    name += "!";
    std::cout << "Hello, " << name << std::endl;
    return number;
}

int main() {
    myMap.insert("my_method_hello", &hello_world ); 
    //  int a = myMap["my_method_hello"]("Tim", 25);
}
```

But I get 12 strange errors on lines with operators:

> ```
> Error 14  error C2665: 'api::apitemp::apitemp' : none of the 2 overloads could convert all the argument types 
> Error 4   error C2586: incorrect user-defined conversion syntax : illegal indirections
> Error 8   error C2586: incorrect user-defined conversion syntax : illegal indirections
> Error 9   error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'const api *' to 'api *'  
> Error 10  error C2439: 'api::apitemp::p' : member could not be initialized    
> Error 13  error C2232: '->api::stringcrint' : left operand has '' type, use '.'   
> Error 2   error C2091: function returns function  
> Error 3   error C2091: function returns function  
> Error 6   error C2091: function returns function  
> Error 7   error C2091: function returns function  
> Error 11  error C2059: syntax error : '[' 
> Error 1   error C2059: syntax error : '*'
> Error 5   error C2059: syntax error : '*'
> Error 12  error C2039: 'p' : is not a member of 'api'
> ```

So I wonder - how to make it compile?

Update: After fixes (thanks to [hvd's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8368976/1056328) ) I we got this:

```
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

template <typename T> struct identity { typedef T type; };
class api {
    //maps containing the different function pointers
    std::map<std::string, identity<void(*)()>::type > voida;
    std::map<std::string, identity<int(*)(std::string, const int&)>::type > stringcrint;
    friend class apitemp;
public:
    //api temp class 
    //given an api and a name, it converts to a function pointer  
    //depending on parameters used
    class apitemp {
        std::string* n;
        api* p;
    public:
        apitemp(std::string* name, api* parent) 
            : n(name), p(parent) {}
        operator identity<void(*)()>::type()
        {return p->voida[*n];}
        operator identity<int(std::string, const int&)>::type*()
        {return p->stringcrint[*n];}
    }; 
    //insertion of new functions into appropriate maps
    void insert(std::string name, void(*ptr)()) 
    {voida[name]=ptr;}
    void insert(std::string name, int(*ptr)(std::string, const int&))
    {stringcrint[name]=ptr;}
    //operator[] for the name gets halfway to the right function
    apitemp operator[](std::string n) {return apitemp(n, this);}
} myMap;

int hello_world(std::string name, const int & number )
{
    name += "!";
    std::cout << "Hello, " << name << std::endl;
    return number;
}

int main() {
    myMap.insert("my_method_hello", &hello_world ); 
        int a = myMap["my_method_hello"]("Tim", 25);
}
```

Yet one error stell stands:

> ```
> Error 1   error C2665: 'api::apitemp::apitemp' : none of the 2 overloads could convert all the argument types
> ```

Comment: sorry but I think you should do your syntax errors with the compiler's help, not ours. there are just too many errors in your code. adding code little by and compiling frequently will make it easier.

Comment: apitemp takes a std::string* yet you pass a std::string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I wrote the orgional code for you I feel obliged to fix it :(

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

class api {
    //maps containing the different function pointers
    typedef void(*voidfuncptr)();
    typedef int(*stringcrintptr)(std::string, const int&);

    std::map<std::string, voidfuncptr> voida;
    std::map<std::string, stringcrintptr> stringcrint;
public:
    //api temp class 
    //given an api and a name, it converts to a function pointer  
    //depending on parameters used
    class apitemp {
        const std::string n;
        const api* p;
    public:
        apitemp(const std::string& name, const api* parent) 
            : n(name), p(parent) {}
        operator voidfuncptr() 
        {return p->voida.find(n)->second;}
        operator stringcrintptr() 
        {return p->stringcrint.find(n)->second;}
    }; 
    //insertion of new functions into appropriate maps
    void insert(const std::string& name, voidfuncptr ptr) 
    {voida[name]=ptr;}
    void insert(const std::string& name, stringcrintptr ptr)
    {stringcrint[name]=ptr;}
    //operator[] for the name gets halfway to the right function
    apitemp operator[](std::string n) const {return apitemp(n, this);}
} myMap;

int hello_world(std::string name, const int & number )
{
    name += "!";
    std::cout << "Hello, " << name << std::endl;
    return number;
}

int main() {
    myMap.insert("my_method_hello", &hello_world ); 
    int a = myMap["my_method_hello"]("Tim", 25);
}
```

http://ideone.com/SXAPu

Answer (score 2):

You can have conversion operators to function pointer types, but the syntax does not let you specify the function type directly. All you need to do is use a typedef, which I've wrapped in a template here:

```
template <typename T> struct identity { typedef T type; };
...
class api {
   // You can use identity<F*>::type
   operator identity<void(*)()>::type();

   // or you can use identity<F>::type*
   operator identity<int(std::string, const int&)>::type*();
};
```

The code has several other errors, such as initializing an api* using a const api* and passing a std::string where a std::string* is wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Declaration containing pointers to functions are mind-bending, so you might first try with a typedef.

```
    typedef void (* no_arg_fun)();
    typedef int (* arg_fun)(std::string, const int&);
    operator no_arg_fun()
    {return p->voida[*n];}
    operator arg_fun()
    {return p->stringcrint[*n];}
```

You also have issues with constness. Map's `operator[]` is a modifying operation, so you either have to use `map::find` instead, or make your own `operator[]` non-const too.

---

There's also unclarity about how you pass parameters. E.g why pass a const pointer to a string rather than a const reference? Why you have functions passing strings by value and ints by const reference (the latter is particularly meaningless, since ints are cheaper to copy).