# Overloading C++ function return type in function map container: automatic deduction fails with compiler error

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors, overloading, return-type

I have simple class like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8304694/1056328) (which behaves like Boost::overload, but has named functions in it ( I use it for simplified\minified reflection\introspection purposes) ). It has problems with multiple return types for input arguments (compiler error 3066). My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

template < class T0, class T1 >
class my_map {
    typedef T0 type_0;
    typedef T1 type_1;
    std::map < std::string, type_0 * >T0_var;
    std::map < std::string, type_1 * >T1_var;
    friend class apitemp;
public:
    my_map(int meaningless0 = 42, int meaningless1 = 42) {} 
    class apitemp {
        std::string n_;
        my_map *p;
    public: 
        apitemp(std::string name_, my_map * parent):n_(name_), p(parent) {}
        operator  type_0 *() {
            return p->T0_var[n_];
        }
        operator  type_1 *() {
            return p->T1_var[n_];
        }
    };
    void insert(std::string name, type_0 * ptr) {
       T0_var[name] = ptr;
    }
    void insert(std::string name, type_1 * ptr) {
       T1_var[name] = ptr;
    }
    apitemp operator[] (std::string n_) {
       return apitemp(n_, this);
    }
};

template<class out, class in1, class in2>
    out hello_world(in1 name, in2 number )
{
    name += "!";
    std::cout << "Hello, " << name << std::endl;
    return number;
}

template<class in1, class in2>
std::string hello_world(in1 name, in2 number )
{
    name += "!";
    std::cout << "Hello, " << name << std::endl;
    return std::string("Yep, we can!");
}

int main() {
    int a =  hello_world<int, std::string, const int &>("Tim", 25);
    std::string b = hello_world<std::string, const int &>("Tim", 25);

    my_map<int(std::string, const int &), std::string(std::string, const int &)> myMap;
    myMap.insert("my_method_hello", &hello_world<int, std::string, const int &> ); 
    myMap.insert("my_method_hello2", &hello_world<std::string, const int &> ); 
    //int a = myMap["my_method_hello"]("Tim", 25); // error C3066: there are multiple ways that an object of this type can be called with these arguments
    //std::string b = myMap["my_method_hello2"]("Tim", 25); // // error C3066: there are multiple ways that an object of this type can be called with these arguments

    std::cin.get();
}
```

How to introduce to its API multiple return type functions? Is it possible in invisiable for API user way? Or at least with something API user disturbing like

```
int a = myMap["my_method_hello"]("Tim", 25)::int; 
std::string b = myMap["my_method_hello2"]("Tim", 25)::string;
```

?

Comment: "Is it possible in invisiable for API user way?" - is that google translation?

Answer (score 3):

One way to do this is to have `myMap["my_method_hello"]("Tim", 25)` return a proxy object that defines `operator int()`, `operator std::string()`, etc for each type you want it to return. Another way is to have the proxy object define explicit `.asInt()`, `.asString()` methods for each type.

The overloaded operator technique can get confusing if the target type isn't explicit in the source code (for example, if you're passing the result to a function). Similarly, the proxy type is likely to confuse template functions you pass it to, and won't be able to easily select an overloaded function if the candidate set includes functions taking both `int` and `std::string` (or other types the proxy auto-converts to. So I recommend providing the `.asInt()`, etc. functions in addition to any operators.

You can also spell the `.asInt()`, etc. functions like `template<typename T> as()` and use explicit specialization to define new conversions. The only downside to this is that the source code gets a bit harder to read.